# Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?

Tags: обсуждение, faq, вопросы, термины

## Для тех, кто задаёт вопросы

Если в комментариях к вашему ответу появилась эта ссылка, значит с точки зрения других участников StackOverflow на русском языке **вы можете значительно улучшить ваш вопрос, прояснив изначальную проблему.**

Пожалуйста, прочитайте ответ к этому вопросу, чтобы понять, что имеют в виду другие участники, и как изменить вопрос, чтобы получить на него наиболее результативный ответ.

## Для тех, кто отвечает на вопросы

Если вы даете ссылку на этот вопрос, постарайтесь также предположить, в чем именно состоит изначальная проблема X. Либо объясните, почему вы считаете, что необходимо прояснить изначальную решаемую проблему.

Комментарий, состоящий только из ссылки, может быть непонятен для автора вопроса и с меньшей вероятностью поможет ему улучшить вопрос. **Используйте ссылку на эту статью как дополнение к вашей аргументации, но не вместо нее**.

## Рекомендую также почитать об этом:

- [Как правильно задавать вопросы, Eric Steven Raymond (перевод)](http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html)
- [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

<sub>Благодарю за помощь в написании ответа участника [alexander barakin](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/alexander-barakin). Этот вопрос и ответ написаны на основе вопроса [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)</sub>

<sub>Обсуждение стилистики и вариантов перевода: [Как перевести “XY Problem”?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/416832/177015)</sub>

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33732/discussion-on-question-by-nick-volynkin-------x).

Comment: Тело вопроса содержит комментарий автора, который не вписывается в сам вопрос и предназначен для прочтения уже после ответа. Этот текст лучше оформить в виде ответа, а в теле вопроса задать сам вопрос как это сделано [в оригинале](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, тут на хабре сей вопрос упомянули: https://habr.com/ru/company/dodopizzaio/blog/467047/

Comment: Кто-нибудь может объяснить, откуда в названии взялся молоток? В оригинале никаких молотков нету, здесь один раз упоминается в одном из примеров. Как он попал в название и зачем?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

## Что такое «Ошибка молотка»

«Ошибка молотка» («Ошибка XY», [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) — это распространенная ошибка тех, кто задает вопросы в сети StackExchange. У спрашивающего есть проблема X, он предполагает, что для неё подходит решение Y и уточняет детали решения. 
При этом он задает вопрос «*Как использовать Y?*» вместо того, чтобы спрашивать «*Как решить X?*».

> [image: Как забивать гвозди молотком?]

## Почему это препятствует нахождению решения

Такая постановка вопроса приводит в замешательство специалистов, пытающихся ответить на вопрос. С их точки зрения решение «Y» часто выглядит никак не связанным с проблемой «X».

В результате усилия как спрашивающего, так и отвечающих участников могут быть потрачены впустую и не привести к решению настоящей проблемы.

## Разве мой вопрос подвержен этой проблеме?

Вероятно, кто-то из участников, являющийся специалистом в области вашего вопроса, предположил, что избранный вами путь решения может вовсе и не являться решением для поставленной задачи. Либо поставленная задача вовсе неясна, а путь решения вызывает сомнения.

Возможно, это и не так. Чтобы развеять сомнения, отредактируйте вопрос, добавив больше информации.

## Как правильно отредактировать вопрос

Чтобы источник проблемы сразу был понятен, придерживайтесь следующих рекоммендаций:

- Всегда давайте информацию о широком контексте проблемы.
- Объясните, почему вы выбрали именно тот путь решения, о котором спрашиваете.
- Если в комментариях участники запрашивают дополнительную информацию — ответьте на их вопросы.

Всё это поможет им найти для вас подходящее решение.

> [image: Как забивать гвозди?]

Comment: Не хватает реальных примеров. Можно улучшить ответ, если просто перевести оригинал.

Comment: @jfs: тот, где про Javascript?

Comment: я знаком только с [одним описанием](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137096)

Comment: @jfs: там шесть ответов есть. Но я понял, о чем речь. Я намеренно вместо дословного перевода ответа решил привести такой пример с микроскопом. Считаете, что нужен прямо совсем из жизни пример?

Comment: достаточно перевести ответ, на который я дал прямую ссылку.

Comment: Реальные примеры будут сильно зависеть от конкретных технологий: не факт, что все с ними будут знакомы или что их популярность не изменится со временем. Молотки и микроскопы -- то, что нужно: и наглядно и понятно всем.

Comment: Реальный пример из сегодняшнего: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/676747/213987

Comment: не следует путать с задачами "похоронного марша", где фактором являются ограничения в ресурсах, времени и доступных инструментах. тогда это "Мне дали задание забить 16 гвоздей микроскопом марки Х с минимальным уроном для микроскопа"

Comment: @NickVolynkin, благо дарю вам, что привели именно такой пример, а не как на английском meta SE. Я неплохо понимаю на английском, но среди всех ответов там я не нашёл более понятного и наглядного примера чем ваш. И самое плохое объяснение в ответе с наибольшим количеством голосов (на который указал jfs) – там очень много лишнего, из-за чего теряется понимание о чём там вообще написано.

Answer (score 16):

## [Что это такое?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137096)

[XY](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)
[вопрос](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) — это вопрос о том, как
исправить неудачную попытку решения задачи, а не о том, как решить саму
задачу.

То есть, кто-то пытается решить задачу `X` и думает что решение
`Y` может сработать. Но оно не срабатывает, и вместо того чтобы напрямую спросить об `X`, автор пытается «спасти» своё решение `Y`, и спрашивает о нём.

## Проблема

Это может помешать людям помочь вам решить задачу, потому
что когда вы задаёте вопрос, решение, с которым возникла
проблема, может не иметь никакой очевидной связи с изначальной задачей.

## Как избежать

Чтобы избежать этого, обязательно включите в свой вопрос информацию о более
широкой картине проблемы, а не только о вашей попытке решения. Если кто-то попросит дать больше информации или уточнить вопрос, дайте нужную информацию.
Если есть другие возможные решения, которые вы рассматривали, но исключили,
не стоит избегать повторного их изложения — наоборот, лучше явно
упомянуть причины, по которым эти решения были отброшены. Так вы предоставите больше информации о том, что вам реально нужно, и поможете
другим дать хорошие ответы.

## Пример

Для примера, лог IRC-чата на канале #python (в переводе):

> <Q> Существует ли функция, которая возвращает строку между двумя разделителями?

> <B> Не понимаю, что ты имеешь ввиду, но сомневаюсь что такая функция есть

> <C> split и slice

> <D> или partition

> <Q> Я пробовал partition

> <Q> Я пытался использовать встроенные функции, чтобы получить число между чем-нибудь подобным в строке: "attribute1: 50.223, attribute2: 442.1"

> <D> почему бы просто не распарсить строку?

> <Q> Я думал, может быть существуют встроенные средства для парсинга

> <D> pairs = [x.strip() for x in s.split(",")]; attribs = {k: v for x in pairs for k, v in x.split(": ")}
>
> <D> есть несколько библиотек, но простейшие форматы легко распарсить вручную -- если не заботиться об обработке ошибок
>
> <D> лучше конечно изменить формат исходных данных на что-нибудь популярное, например, json или yaml, если возможно

> <Q> Эти данные на самом деле из HTML
>
> <Q> но я не знаю как парсить Javascript HTMLParser'ом или как он там называется

> <D> Данные просто внутри html или они ещё чем-то обработаны?

> <Q> просто внутри

> <D> если это javascript (похоже на него, за исключением внешних скобок), json вероятно может распарсить это

> <Q> спасибо

> <D> Я не сказал это явно: json понимает только данные, не js-код

> <Q> Всё что мне нужно распарсить — это данные

Задача на самом деле о том как [раcпознать в Питоне структуры данных Javascript, присутствующие в HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13323976/4279),
а не о том как *"найти строку между двумя разделителями"*. При этом
требуется достаточно много времени и интуиции, чтобы добраться до
реальной проблемы.

Это легче сделать в полностью интерактивном чате, а не на сайте StackExchange, где сообщение полируется немного, отправляется,
и затем кто-то реагирует через 5-30 минут (или даже позже).
Поэтому гораздо легче двигаться в правильном направлении с самого начала.

Comment: Не стесняйтесь редактировать, если замечены ошибки в переводе (английский текст включён в виде комментариев в md-разметке). Приветствуются правки, которые не изменяют смысла исходного английского текста.

Comment: Интересно какой глубины может достигать рекурсия в самых клинических случаяx? Хотел бы я посмотреть на проблему **M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z**