# Стоит ли насильно редактировать вопрос, если половина оного в комментариях

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

По [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476368/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-mysql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) вопросу хотелось бы принять решение.
Суть вопроса стала ясна только в комментариях, вопрос никто не редактировал, чтоб уточнить.

Если принять, что вопрос про ограничение запросов, то ответ LEQADA вполне нормальный. Ответ пользователя Ипатьев совсем не по теме, это, по сути, комментарий к вопросу.

Вопрос сам не раскрыт сейчас до конца. По сути проблема топикстартера - защита от инъекций (из комментариев).

По-хорошему, следует ли его поправить на что-то вроде "как защитить от инъекций", после того, как на исходный вопрос - тот, что в теле вопроса, а не в комментариях - был дал ответ, или нужно оставить вопрос как есть?

Хотелось бы обсудить, чтоб как-то в будущем решать такие вопросы.

Comment: Ну вот, теперь закрыли, как дубликат вообще не по теме -_-

Comment: @LEQADA Не волнуйтесь, его еще и запросто переоткроют

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Насколько мне кажется, последовательность действий должна быть такова:

1. В результате обсуждения в комментариях выяснилось, что вопрос сформулирован неверно, в нём отсутствуют важные данные, нужные для понимания проблемы.
2. Нужно попросить автора внести эти данные в вопрос. Он, в конце-концов, может/должен сформулировать это так, как ему кажется правильным/понятным.
3. Если автор забросил вопрос, и/или не хочет вносить нужные данные в него, необходимо самостоятельно исправить вопрос. Исправленный вопрос лучше, чем неправильно сформулированный.
4. Если автор открыто противится исправлению вопроса, его мнением, после обсуждения с модераторами, можно и пренебречь. Возможно, стоит просто поставить кастомную тревогу и объяснить модератору, в чём дело.

Comment: В ответах люди с опытом SQL не стали редактировать вопрос, либо потому что не разобрались в проблеме, либо ещё почему-то. Если автор не захочет сам редактировать вопрос, то кто это будет делать?

Comment: (1) автор, (2) благожелательные участники, (3) модератор, (4) никто, если никто не заметил. В таком порядке.

Answer (score 10):

На мой взгляд, типичная [XY-проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709). В комментариях автор дает понять, что забивает гвозди микроскопом (его цель явно указана в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476368/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-mysql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85#comment541402_476368)) и вообще не в курсе что есть молоток и не понимает как вообще можно забивать чем-то кроме микроскопа.

Следует показать в ответах как надо делать и что текущая постановка вопроса не имеет смысла, учитывая его цель. Вопрос можно оставить как есть и даже открыть его, при условии, что подобный ответ будет более заметен, чем почти 30 комментариев.

PS. Может быть даже оставить строчку в конце самого вопроса, что вообще речь совсем не о том и так делать не стоит.

Comment: Хех, приятно видеть, что мы с Alexander Barakin не зря иллюстрации делали. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Это да. Только сейчас заметил, что не плюсанул это топик. Исправился :)

Answer (score 9):

Стоит ли вносить улучшающую правку? – Да. Всегда и при любых условиях, на любой стадии решения вопроса. Именно для этого движок выдает привилегии на редактирование чужих вопросов и ответов.

Если вы видите, что можете улучшить сообщение, не важно чем, переносом комментариев в тело, удалением ненужной информации, добавлением нужной – пожалуйста, сделайте это! Размещая информацию на Stack Overflow, автор получает решение, в случае вопроса, признание и авторитет, в случае ответа, но знания, представленные в сообщении, становятся достоянием всего сообщества, а не отдельных людей. Вопрос задается и получает ответ один раз, а читается множество. Наша задача, как более опытных участников, адаптировать содержимое под чтения для наших коллег.

Answer (score 4):

Сейчас есть:

1. Вопрос про ограничение операторов.
2. Дополнение в комментарии, что на самом деле нужно.
3. Ответы на оба эти вопроса.

Что нужно сделать?

- Можно просто ничего не делать, поскольку всё уже есть.
- Можно дополнить вопрос, просто скопировав  в конец текст комментария.

Делать что либо ещё не вижу смысла.

Answer (score 4):

Вся необходимая для ответа информация должна быть в вопросе. Попросите автора или сами перенесите необходимую информацию из комментариев.

Если вопрос "как забивать гвозди микроскопом", то следует отвечать именно на этот вопрос, даже если в 99999 случаях из 100000 автору следовало бы взять молоток (естественно, следует упомянуть молоток в ответе).

Если ещё ответов нет, то можно исправить вопрос (превратить его в просто "как забивать гвозди") на основе информации в комментариях.

Если уже есть ответы, то не следует менять вопрос таким образом, что делает текущие ответы неверными. Следует новый вопрос задать.

Answer (score -1):

Конкретно этот вопрос я бы удалил.

Редактировать его - это будет совсем глупо, поскольку в отредактированном виде он будет дубликатом.
Оставить как есть - это был бы вариант, если бы в нем не было комментариев, показывающих намерения автора. Несчастный язык РНР и так битком набит самыми дикими суевериями, и незачем оставлять вопрос, косвенно пропагандирующий одно из них.

Банальный ответ про про запрос GRANT лучше оставить для вопроса, автору которого нужно будет ограничение прав само по себе, а не как бессмысленное и неприменимое средство от SQL инъекций. Как вариант предлагаю автору ответа сочинить новый вопрос, и самому себе на него ответить. Правилами это не возбраняется.

Answer (score -2):

Последовательность, на самом деле, была такая (можете читать по жирным, если слишком много букв):

1. **Вопрос был задан "Как разрешить исполнение заранее заданных команд в
   MySQL".**
2. **В комментариях на вопрос** его автор объявил истинную причину этого желания -
   **оказалось, что он хочет таким образом защититься от SQL-инъекций**.
3. На вопрос было дано **3 ответа (один из которых был принят)**,
   автор одного из которых обладал действительно хорошими знаниями по
   меркам StackOverflow (имеет золотой бадж по MySQL). **Ни один из них
   не стал редактировать вопрос**, чтобы привести его к виду, на который
   они отвечают.
4. **Я ответил на вопрос**, поставленный автором **и под принятым ответом
   написал, что он неверный**, таким образом **предотвращая проблему тех,
   кто в будущем попадёт на этот вопрос из поисковиков**.

   ---

#### Моё мнение:

Я считаю, что теперь не имеет смысла редактировать вопрос вручную, а следует дождаться автора вопроса для этого. Если автор вопроса не явится либо не захочет редактировать, то редактирование этого вопроса другими пользователями считаю неправильным, так как был дан ответ, соответствующий исходному вопросу.

---

#### UPDATE

На текущий момент мой ответ принят автором вопроса, как верный.