# Приветствуется ли правка вопроса "под корень", если он не соответствует проблеме?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, правки

Вопрос у меня возник после [ответа человеку здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554849/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-preventdefault).

Его вопрос решен, он доволен. А меня мучает нестерпимое желание под корень исправить его вопрос, потому что ни заголовок ни текст вопроса не соответствуют проблеме. Из поиска сюда могут придти, разве что, на ответ. Сам вопрос описывает совершенно, казалось бы, не связанные с проблемой вещи.

Сам вопрос поставлен верно (насколько я могу судить). Он верно описал свою проблему и привел верный участок кода. Но вместо вопроса "у меня не работает preventDefault()" теперь должен быть вопрос "у меня не работает .load() и вот такая ошибка в консоли" и другое описание ситуации.

Теперь, когда его проблема решена и вопрос ему, по большому счету, не важен, хочется привести вопрос в такой вид, чтобы он и заголовком и телом описывал саму суть проблемы. Чтобы люди, попадали сюда из поиска и думали "вот! оно! прямо как у меня!".

Но не будет ли такое отношение неприятным для автора вопроса? Вероятно, следует сначала попросить его переформулировать вопрос? Но ведь придется, буквально, говорить ему текст, если он сам не до конца понял проблему.

Даже я, еще совсем "зеленый" здесь, оказываюсь перед ситуацией несоответствия вопроса и проблемы уже не первый раз. Хочется понять, какой план действий желателен?

Не нашел здесь обсуждения на эту тему, которое дало бы мне однозначный ответ. [Вот этот тред](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2134/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85) очень похож, но конкретики немного. Вроде все указывает на то, что можно и нужно, но я хочу получить однозначное согласие сообщества с этой точкой зрения.

Comment: я бы предложил исправить + упомянуть что используется новый jQuery,  прямо в теле вопроса

Answer (score 1):

**Когда стоит редактировать сообщения?**

Если вам кажется, что сообщение можно улучшить, и вы готовы этим заняться.

Основные причины для редактирования:

1. исправить грамматические или орфографические ошибки;
2. прояснить суть сообщения, не изменяя его;
3. исправить мелкие погрешности или, если информация устарела, дополнить или обновить;
4. дополнить ссылками или указать полезные ресурсы по теме.

Редактируя сообщение, стремитесь к тому, чтобы существенно улучшить его смысл, а не просто изменить буковку-другую. Незначительные правки не приветствуются.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit  выдержка от сюда. Тут помойму довольно конкретно говориться что правьте..

Comment: Я не увидел здесь однозначного ответа, применимого к ситуации. На мой взгляд, она не попадает ни под один из четырех пунктов. Фактически, мне нужно не улучшить сообщение, а подогнать его под проблему. Даже если сам вопрос построен верно и решает свою задачу для автора. Постоянно приходит в голову аналогия с SEO-текстами, где качество текста вторично, по сравнению с основной задачей - привлечь пользователя. Собственно, эта ситуация и имеет место в нашем случае.

Comment: Ну вот же `2. пояснить суть сообщения, не изменяя его` тут вы просто изменив тайтл вы как рас поясните суть вопроса. Да и первое предложение говорит о том что `Если вам кажется, что сообщение можно улучшить, и вы готовы этим заняться.` стоит поправить.

Comment: Так речь же о том, чтобы полностью переписать вопрос. Задать другой вопрос вместо существующего. Не уверен, что автору это понравится.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын, не думаю, что имеет смысл менять чужой текст столь кардинально, просто создайте **новый вопрос** и сами же ответьте на него.