# Неправильное объединение двух разных ответов

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

На этот вопрос [Как сделать HTTPS запрос с защитой от MITM?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524167/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-https-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82-mitm#557840) я сделал 2 разных ответа, которые @PashaPash зачем-то объединил. Не понимаю, зачем? Это 2 разных взгляда на проблему, и решаются они по разному, не нужна тут такая простыня.

**Уберите, пожалуйста этого модератора от вопроса, он мне уже угрожает на ровном месте.**

Comment: Он это [любит](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/522931/178988).

Comment: Это беспредел. Если нет понимания в тематике вопроса, не надо его трогать, @PashaPash. Вот минус я уже получил и гадаю, за что же он: за простыню, которую PashaPash так любезно предоставил, или кто-то не согласен с одной из версий ответа (какой конкретно - уже не узнаем).

Comment: Вообще говоря, один из этих ответов неправильный, т. к. ломает идею асимметричного шифрования и, на мой взгляд, подлежит удалению. Но почему ответы объединили, мне тоже интересно.

Comment: Идеологически неправильный, но не технически. В некоторых случаях приходится идти и на это (см. комментарий в ответе).

Comment: Да неважно. Мы тут пытаемся понять, чего это два существенно разных ответа оказались объединены :)

Comment: А почему вы сами не хотели дать два разных ответа, перечислив их в одном? Так постоянно делается, от самых кратких http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554885/ и до весьма развёрнутых типа такого: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/

Comment: Странный вопрос, я же объяснил вначале уже. Один - простой, но небезопасный. Второй - легальный, но с некоторыми зависимостями.

Comment: Код на делфи и не требовался, было поступление и для C. Еще раз: я пояснил минусы первого ответа в начале второго, это как раз должно было снять все вопросы по безопасности метода. Не понимаю, зачем после этого еще и минусовать. Я не удалю ответ, он технически верный.

Comment: Господа, давайте не будем сделать здесь филиал ветки комментариев под обсуждаемым ответом. У нас тут немножко другая тема. Предлагаю почистить нерелевантные комментарии.

Comment: "Отпугивающая надпись была в первом абзатце второго ответа" и "я пояснил минусы первого ответа в начале второго, это как раз должно было снять все вопросы по безопасности метода" -- как по мне, это только дополнительные аргументы за единый пост. Отпугивающая надпись логически относится к первому посту, но вы её относите в другой пост (вы же понимаете, что они не обязательно подряд будут отображаться?) и продолжаете уже совсем другой ответ.

Comment: "но вы её относите в другой пост (вы же понимаете, что они не обязательно подряд будут отображаться?) и продолжаете уже совсем другой ответ" -- поэтому, там была еще ссылка на первый ответ. Надпись вначале второго потому что я еще и понимал, что второй вопрос будет выше первого, я лишь выдержал хронологию.

Comment: @mega вы исходите из того, что у меня "нет понимания в тематике вопроса". Выглядит странно приводить два ответа (причем оба неполных и не до конца правильных) раздельными ответами. Движок сайта показывает ответы не по времени добавления, а по голосам - к моему приходу в топик второй ответ уже висел выше первого. И да, оба ваших ответа не решают задачу - ни задачу топикастера, ни задачу защиты от MITM.

Comment: _Движок сайта показывает ответы не по времени добавления, а по голосам_ - сортировка у каждого пользователя своя, там три вида их

Comment: @mega Пожалуйста, поясните утверждение «Уберите, пожалуйста этого модератора от вопроса, он мне уже угрожает на ровном месте.». Как мне кажется, данный вопрос (каким правилом следует руководствоваться при публикации ответов) – вполне типичный для сообщества. С большой вероятностью, конкретный модератор тут не причем.

Comment: Не понял, что пояснить. В этом вопросе речь только об одном конкретном модераторе.

Comment: @mega Имелось в виду, что модератор никоем образом не угрожает. Ко всему, модератор одновременно является и обычным участником сообщества, который активно участвует в решении задач, выражая свою профессиональную позицию. К сожалению, не всегда ясно, какую роль в данный момент он играет. На мой взгляд, ответы были объединены на правах модератора, в полном соответствии с правилами сообщества, а дальнейший диалог, в том числе в чате, был между двумя знатоками имеющими равные привелегии на сайте.

Comment: В ходе дальнейшего диалога, когда у модератора не осталось аргументов, он принялся угрожать мне удалением вопроса, а в последствие - удалил этот комментарий.

Comment: "удалением вопроса" -- удалением ответа

Comment: @mega во первых - я не угрожал - легко проверить, этот коментарий практически продублирован в моем ответе ниже. Во вторых - комментарии удалял не я, а Nicolas Chabanovsky - на случай, если вы решили что я "заметаю следы"

Comment: На каком основании вы выбрали один из ответов тут как принятый? Обычно итог подводится после окончания обсуждения, а не в процессе. Уберите "галочку", не позорьтесь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По моему мнению, **2 или несколько различных ответов на вопрос должны располагаться в разных сообщениях**.

---

Долго не вступал в эту дискуссию с надеждой увидеть аргументы оппонентов. Но таковых что-то не нашёл.

> Голоса на ответах должны показывать общую полезность вклада участника. А не служить для выбора варианта по вкусу сообщества.
>
> Если варианты решения не дополняют друг друга, а просто предлагают разные пути решения одной проблемы - они тем более должны быть одним ответом.
>
> Чем более полный и содержательней ответ вы публикуете, тем лучше. Как результат, даже если проблему можно решить несколькими способами, лучшей стратегией будет публикация одного ответа, содержащего несколько подходов.

Почему «должны», «лучше»? Можно обоснования кроме «тут так принято»?

> Текущий формат SO подразумевает, что разные решения одной проблемы от одного автора должны быть собраны в один ответ. "Тут так принято".

---

### Аналогичный вопрос на общей Мете

Собственно, где «принято»? Даже на этой Мете, как и ув-мый mega, я не вижу [«единогласно»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3556/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2?cb=1#comment11451_3560).

Как [говорил Nicolas](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3560/199934), "изначально система проектировалась как «одно сообщение (вопрос или ответ) от одного участника»". Но зачем-то ведь ввели возможность публикации дополнительных ответов? Значит это кому-нибудь нужно?

Читаем начало самого популярного [ответа на общей Мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice/25211#25211) с 64 голосами.

> When you have two distinct answers, it's better to post two different answers than to put them both into one answer.

Перевод:

> Когда у вас есть 2 различных ответа, лучше помещать их 2 различных сообщения, чем объединять в одно сообщение.

[Следующий по популярности ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25229/326972) с 19-ю голосами также поддерживает идею разделения ответов.

Выходит, принято как раз обратное?

---

### Аргументация Lance Roberts:

> Some questions will be multiple-answer types directly, like in Meta topics where aspects of features are wanted as feedback. This allows the ones the community feels are the best/correct to float to the top.
>
> Some computer languages have a lot of flexibility in how to solve any one problem, so by listing them both as separate answers (if very distinct) they can both be voted on by the community, and this will allow the better answer to float to the top. It also allows the comment threads to be more focused on each answer.
>
> If you put two very different answers in one, then one could be a great answer, and one could be a terrible way to do things, but the upvotes (or downvotes) on the good (or bad) answer will drag the other along with it to the top (or bottom).

Того самого ответа с 64 голосами. Разберём её.

1. Некоторые компьютерные языки позволяют решить задачу различными способами.

Инструменты для программирования также. Хоть, вероятно, большинство вопросов, на которые можно дать несколько вариантов ответа, и [являются «опросниками»](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25211/326972), но такие отнюдь не все. И на вопросы, соответствующие тематике Stack Overflow, вполне можно дать несколько ответов.

2. Комментарии по каждому ответу располагаются в соответствующем месте.

Если сообщение содержит несколько ответов, комментарии по любой из частей сообщения смешиваются в кучу. Это не очень дружественно для пользователей. мне удобнее писать на issue trackers: одна тема — одно обсуждение, чем на условный Ru-Board, где все обсуждения по одной программе перемежаются друг с другом.

3. В объединённом сообщении могут содержаться как хорошие, так и плохие ответы. А плюс/минус только один.

Допустим, в сообщении содержится несколько хороших ответов и один плохой. Будут минусовать именно за этот один плохой.

---

### Аргументация Саши Черных

#### Основной аргумент

1. **Должны оцениваться ответы, а не участники**

Положим, я столкнулся с проблемой, и поисковик привёл меня на Stack Overflow. В первую очередь я обращаю внимание на самые заплюсованные ответы, которые не всегда, но обычно и являются лучшими. Если плохой и хороший ответ располагаются в различных сообщениях, первый обычно минусуют, второй наоборот наберёт плюсы. Скорее всего я не обращу внимания на заминусованный, но буду делать так, как расписано в заплюсованном.

Но если эти ответы в разных сообщениях, я не смогу понять, какой из них принять за руководство к действию. Выберу плохой и потеряю время. Поэтому для меня лучше, если они будут в разных сообщениях.

#### Дополнительный аргумент

2. По мне так комфортнее читать множество разделённых обособленных развёрнутых ответов, нежели «простыню», получающуюся, если объединить их.

#### Ответы на контраргумент

> Разделением ответов участники «активно пытаются нафармить репутацию».

1. Полагаю, вряд ли многими участниками, способными выдавать по 2 ответа на вопрос, движет такая цель. Но даже если так, чем это плохо для Stack Overflow? Если вы в состоянии выдать 2 или более хороших ответов, разве не заслуживаете репутацию за каждый из них? За плохие наоборот вам придётся ей поплатиться.
2. Как [говорил PashaPash](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3562/199934), «Движок сайта активно сопротивляется наличию нескольких ответов от одного участника. Особенно проблема усугубляется при 3+ ответах - любая попытка проголосовать за все три ответа воспринимается как накрутка и откатывается.»

Answer (score 9):

У второго ответа написано что это дополнение к другому ответу. Дополнения должны вноситься правками в ответ, а не созданием отдельных ответов. По этому ответы были объединены.

Другими словами, хотите сделать два ответа - не пишите что один это дополнение у другому.

Comment: Нет, слово "дополнение" ни как не означает, что ответы следует объединить. Они совершенно разные. И спор как раз по первому ответу, и минусы по нему. Оба эти ответа решают задачу, причем, по-разному.

Answer (score 7):

Типичная практика на сайте приводить в ответе несколько возможных решений: как грамотный инженер вы показываете из своего опыта сразу несколько вариантов, возможные плюсы и минусы каждого подхода.

В качестве примера могу привести как очень краткие ответы (см. [Как передать открытый ключ на сервер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554885/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80)), так и весьма подробные (см. [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-git))

Возможно, те, кто активно пытаются нафармить репутацию и видят какой-то толк от такого разделения ответов; я – не вижу.

Также по комментариям топикстартера я вижу, что "разные" ответы были связаны общей нитью повествования: "Отпугивающая надпись была в первом абзаце второго ответа" и "я пояснил минусы первого ответа в начале второго, это как раз должно было снять все вопросы по безопасности метода".

Какими соображениями руководствовался PashaPash я не знаю, возможно он сам пояснит.

Могу сказать, что на месте топикстартера я бы считал вполне нормальным, что ответы были объединены.

Тем не менее, поскольку автор настаивает, что хочет в данном случае видеть ответы раздельными – я предлагаю пойти навстречу и разделить ответы обратно:

Мы на StackOverflow часто правим и улучшаем ответы друг друга, стараясь при этом не исказить первоначальный смысл ([линк](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2134/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85), [ещё один](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3537/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5/3538#3538)) – и здесь, видимо, применимо то же самое правило: если автор считает, что его исходный замысел был искажен – то ответ(ы) необходимо восстановить в первозданном виде.

Answer (score 5):

Как устроивший [модераторский-произвол](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb), хотел бы пояснить ситуацию:

Без привязки к конкретному случаю:

1. Если варианты решения дополняют друг друга - они должны быть одним ответом.
2. Если варианты решения не дополняют друг друга, а просто предлагают разные пути решения одной проблемы - они *тем более* должны быть одним ответом, с обоснованием - когда и какой вариант использовать.

Голоса на ответах должны показывать общую полезность вклада участника. А не служить для выбора варианта по вкусу сообщества.

---

Движок сайта активно сопротивляется наличию нескольких ответов от одного участника. Особенно проблема усугубляется при 3+ ответах - любая попытка проголосовать за все три ответа воспринимается как накрутка и откатывается.

---

По конкретному случаю. Что просил топикастер:

> Нужен **пример кода** для скачивания странички или файла по https протоколу с проверкой подлиности то есть, что бы в сессию нельзя было вклинится и подделать ответ. Все это дело будет **на делфи 7** но устроит и **код на си** можно использовать winapi (Win7+) и/или openSSL dll'ку.

Что было бы полноценным ответом в этом случае:

1. Пример кода на делфи 7 + обоснование защиты им от MITM
2. Пример кода на C + обоснование защиты им от MITM

Просто обоснование каких-то общих методов защиты от MITM (все зависимости от их технической правильности, которая лично у меня вызывает сомнения) не может быть ответом на вопрос, в котором автор явно попросил пример кода.

Два "ответа" с таким обоснованием и посылом в гугл за исходниками - тем более.

Comment: о! теперь мы знаем, что при голосовании за три ответа - будут откаты, осталось узнать временной промежуток, и можно будет накручивать по два плюса :-)

Comment: @Grundy 3 - выведено эмпирически, на основе моего голосования в http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522931/. Долгосрочные схемы накрутки все равно хорошо видны, и за них в конце концов банят )

Comment: С учетом того, что вопрос был задан аж в мае, я счел свой скромный вклад более чем полезным, и в накрутке репутации уж точно не был замечен никогда. К тому же, учитывая, что автор не приложил и строчки кода, я ему сделал намек на то, что если бы он хотя бы что-то с этой стороны предпринял, ответ можно было бы расширить и кодом, т.к. писать работу за автора у нас не принято. Обоснования @PashaPash расцениваю как последний довод в оправдание своих действий, хотя мне до его переживаний совсем нет дела, я просто хочу, чтобы он вернул мои ответы в первоначальный вид и больше не трогал.

Comment: @mega я, кажется, достаточно подробно изложил свою позицию выше - ваш ответ (оба ваших ответа) не являются ответами на вопрос, заданный топикастером. У меня был выбор - или удалить оба, или оставить один, в качестве *исключения*, из уважения к вам и потраченному вами времени. Если вы хотели изложить два разных варианта решения какой-то проблемы - вам стоило расположить их в одном ответе, в порядке, в котором вы их советуете применять.

Comment: @mega может быть конкретный пример поможет. скажем, вы придумываете третий вариант решения, какой-нибудь самописный обмен ключами поверх https. вы запостите его 3-м ответом? а если вы придумаете еще, например, peer trust  - 4-м?

Comment: @Grundy, следует уточнить, что речь о трёх минусах. Три плюса НЕ откатываются - проверено лично.

Answer (score 2):

Изначально система проектировалась как «одно сообщение (вопрос или ответ) от одного участника». [Если вопрос допускает два ответа от одного участника, с большой вероятностью, это вопрос–опросник](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25211/274323).

Именно поэтому, когда вы находитесь в вопросе, к которому вы еще не опубликовали ответ, имеется поле ввода ответа, но если вы на странице вопроса, к которому вы уже дали ответ, вы видите лишь кнопку, при клике на которую, вам необходимо подтвердить ваше намерение.

Чем более полный и содержательней ответ вы публикуете, тем лучше. Как результат, даже если проблему можно решить несколькими способами, лучшей стратегией будет публикация одного ответа содержащего несколько подходов, как было подчеркнуто в ответе [@A K](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3558/6).

Comment: Это 2 совершенно разных ответа, для 2-х разных ситуаций. У нас и оффтопик поднялся как раз по первому ответу. Второй вообще не обсуждается. Я понимал это, когда разделил ответы. И это как раз тот самый случай, когда чистый ответ нужно оставить в покое, он правильный. Кроме того, я не люблю простынки, их читать невозможно и не нужно. Причем замечание по поводу небезопасности первого подхода я сделал. Тут должно быть 2 отдельных решения, нельзя их смешивать, как альтернативы, они не равны!

Comment: @mega В ответе рассмотрен общий случай. Если вы считаете, что в отдельно взятом случае следует разбить ответ на два, и это не противоречит правилам и мнению сообщества, возможно, так и стоит сделать.

Comment: В первом ответе рассматривается общий случай, и решение для него будет работать всегда. Во втором ответе рассмотрен частный случай, когда для него подготовлена инфраструктура на стороне сервера. Именно из-за резонанса в принятии сообществом первого ответа, его нельзя объединять со вторым. Некоторые просто не понимают разницу между безопасностью ключа и безопасностью диалога. Какие противоречия у Вас тут вызывают эти 2 ответа, и почему до сих пор не возвращены правки модератора?

Comment: @mega  Судя по ответам здесь, на Мете, сообщество единогласно поддерживает вариант одного–ответа–в–одном–вопросе, как в общем случае, так и в этом конкретном. Общая логика в том, что приведенные ответы описывают альтернативные подходы, которые лучше рассмотреть в одном ответе.

Comment: Где это "единогласно"? Хватит уже выгораживать PashaPash. Общая логика SO в том, чтобы найти правильный ответ, а не объединить все резонансные в одном. По Вашей логике выходит, что на каждый вопрос должен быть один ответ.

Comment: @mega Как я понял, каждый ответ в этом вопросе говорит о том, что все за один ответ в одном вопросе. Именно под этим я имел в виду «единогласно». Согласно такой же логике проектировалась вся система Stack Exchange – один участник дает один максимально развернутый ответ по теме, выражая в нем весь свой опыт.

Comment: @mega Более того, Джоел Спольски не раз [высказывал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ), что один из лучших, по его мнению, способов получения репутации на сайте – найти вопрос с несколькими неполными ответами, собрать все ответы в один, добавив результаты своих исследований, тестов и т. д.

Comment: @mega да, не единогласно. за вариант "оставить один ответ" 7 за, 2 против. за вариант "оставить один ответ, но может быть в данном конкретном случае разделить (а может быть и нет!)" на котором вы поставили зеленый чекбокс - 4 за, 1 против. т.е. по сути за разделение всего два человека - вы, и кто-то еще. Против - минимум 7. Ответа "разделить, потому что ...., и постить все новые варианты той же проблемы новыми ответами" - вообще нет. Соответственно, правки не возвращены, т.к. никто не поддержал идею разделения.

Comment: @mega текущий формат SO подразумевает, что разные решения одной проблемы от одного автора должны быть собраны в один ответ. "тут так принято". для изменения формата требуется активная поддержка другими участниками. хотя бы в виде голосов на мете.

Comment: "за вариант "оставить один ответ" 7 за, 2 против. за вариант "оставить один ответ, но может быть в данном конкретном случае разделить (а может быть и нет!)" на котором вы поставили зеленый чекбокс - 4 за, 1 против. т.е. по сути за разделение всего два человека - вы, и кто-то еще. Против - минимум 7" -- да Вы прям счетовод, смешно! Nicolas, остановите этот абсурд, верните правки.

Comment: @mega вы переходите на личности. пожалуйста, перестаньте.

Answer (score -1):

Я считаю, к публикации второго ответа применим следующий критерий:

> Что бы вы сделали, если бы первый ответ был от другого участника? Дополнили бы его (путем комментария, заимствования или упоминания) - или опубликовали бы другой ответ без каких-бы то ни было упоминаний первого?

Если ни один ответ не может выглядеть как дополнение для другого - то два разных ответа допустимы.

---

В этом плане модератор, по моему мнению, был прав - второй ответ был явно написан как логическое продолжение первого:

> **дополнение к исходному ответу.**
>
> В большинстве случаев, **приватный ключ Вам доступен не будет** *(продолжение повествования)*. Это логично, на то он и "приватный", чтобы гарантировать безопасность только диалога, а не всей цепочки посредников, так или иначе, вовлеченных в "беседу".
>
> Поэтому я приведу **еще один** оч. хороший вариант, т.н. - сertificate authority.

Comment: Звучит как оправдание действий модератора: "а подберем-ка причину исходя из решения" ))

Comment: @mega разумеется, если я оправдываю действия модератора - мое сообщение будет звучать как оправдание действия модератора.

Comment: @mega а вот вы, видимо, способны воспринимать лишь поддержку в свою сторону, но не критику.