# Уход от проблемы вместо её решения

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

Если есть техническая возможность, я ставлю минусы, когда на вопрос «У меня в "Опере" такая-то проблема» следует ответ «Юзай Хром». Т.е. программный продукт, о котором заходит речь в вопросе, достаточно распространённый, а отвечающий советует пользоваться другим.

Пример ответа: [Тонкая настройка LiveReload под Sublime Text 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/531785/1). Автор советует советует снести LiveReload, у которого [227 тысяч загрузок](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LiveReload) и поставить BrowserSync. Сам пользуюсь ReloadEvery, не знаю, возможно, BrowserSync действительно лучше и меньше глючит, но **означенной в вопросе проблемы ответ не решает**, проблема с LiveReload не устранена.

Хотелось узнать, как сообщество относится к подобным ответам, предпринимаете ли в их отношении какие-то действия.

Comment: Вы можете выразить свое отношение к вопросу/ответу при помощи *минуса* и тревоги: *Не является ответом на вопрос*

Comment: @Bald кстати в том вопросе сам автор себе как ответ и написал. А это вообще никак не правильно. Имхо надо расстреливать его)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я видел что это самоответ, принципиальной разницы не вижу кем дан ответ самим пользователем задавшим вопрос или кем то иным, алгоритм будет тем же: *Минус*, *Тревога*. возможно комментарий поясняющий минус

Comment: Нередко смена инструмента - это и есть решение проблемы. Упомянутый вопрос можно было бы переформулировать без привязки к исходному инструменту, тогда ответ стал бы корректным.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну или более развернутый ответ, почему то, лучше чем это. Например в том случае: у LiveReload нет такой опции и вообще у него мало опций для тонкой настройки, а у технологии N - есть то-то, то-то и много еще то-то, поэтому как вариант взглянуть на....

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, чем плохи самомответы?

Comment: @Александр, ничем, здесь они даже поощряются. Обсуждение не о самоответах (см. комментарий Bald выше), а о разновидности ответов.

Comment: @Александр я разве сказал, что самоответ- это плохо? Нет. Самоответ тоже хорошо. Я вам уже писал, цитирую: `что просто надо обосновать почему, а не просто сказать "удалите нафиг то, поставьте это". Например сказать, что у LiveReload нет такой опции (если действительно её нет) или еще каких-либо опций, а другой технологии есть, а также у другой технологии есть боле тонкие настройки и такие-то такие-то вещи, которые более помогают решать те и те проблемы...... вот тогда ответ действительно будет хоть как-то оправданным`

Comment: @Александр, извините, если что вопрос никак не связан лично с Вами.

Comment: Вопрос (который здесь, на этой странице) хороший, но пример (по ссылке) так себе. За рекомендацией BrowserSync вы не заметили собственно ответа: "у "LiveReload" нет такой опции, которая могла бы решить мою проблему". Это ответ "никак". Заодно отвечающий на мгновенно возникающий вопрос "и что делать?" в качестве бонуса. А вообще, зацикливание на инструментах в разработке ПО и потому применение их не по назначению это крупная проблема, которая приводит к большим потерям времени вникуда.

Comment: @D-side, [**редакция ответа**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/531785/1), когда я написал этот вопрос на Мету.

Comment: Это я упустил, да. Приложите ссылку в вопрос что ли.

Comment: Великий и всемогущий модератор "PashaPash" просто удалил ответ - так видно гораздо лучше, чтобы никто не узнал про альтернативу и мучался с тем решением, что дано и является типа "правильным". Ну ок, раз у вас тут так заведено.

Comment: @Александр, лично я не понимаю, зачем понадобилось удалять Ваш обновлённый ответ, и каким правилам соответствует удаление. Попробуйте открыть новую тему здесь, на Мете, может, последуют объяснения.

Comment: @Саша Черных, не буду ничего открывать, я просто написал новый ответ, считаю что он может быть полезен другим, и так настаиваю на своём ответе исходя из этого. Тем более у него было 4 положительных оценки. 
А вот модератор руководствуется правилом "потому что я могу", вот и удалил. Не хочу связываться с таким человеком, ничего уже не буду открывать.

Comment: Из недавнего: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7858/15479

Answer (score 15):

### Когда как

Если в вопросе конкретная проблема, которую автор хочет решить в конкретной среде, а ему навязчиво и неаргументированно приводят что-то другое ("X" какашка, юзай "Y"!!1) - **минус и тревога**.

Если в вопросе конкретная проблема, которую автор хочет решить в определенной среде, а ему приводят что-то другое в качестве альтернативы (и аргументируют целесообразность перехода). Или если вопрос звучит скорее как [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709) - **ничего или плюс**.

Comment: [**Здесь**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571893/199934), получается, ничего или плюс? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Мое имхо по конкретно этому ответу - указать в комментариях на некорректность и забыть.

Answer (score 6):

Если вопрос «как распознать html, используя регулярные выражения», то обязательно стоит *упомянуть, что [в общем случае это не возможно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4279)*, но при этом *привести [ответ, который отвечает на вопрос как есть](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1736801/4279)* (c подходящими оговорками).

Не стоит минусовать ответ, который решает подразумеваемую проблему, даже если он не является ответом, если вопрос воспринимать буквально, так как даже если автор вопроса находится в редкой ситуации, когда предупреждения о его выбранном пути решения задачи можно проигнорировать, большинство будущих посетителей из веб-поисковика получат пользу от общепринятого решения неявной проблемы из вопроса.

То есть в общем случае, на вопрос: «как сделать X, используя Y», вполне можно ответить «Y плохо подходит для X по причинам A,B,C, используйте Z вместо этого». И в качестве дополнения (например, если у автора уникальная ситуация когда он вынужден использовать `Y` вместо `Z`), с оговорками, указать путь как сделать `X`, используя `Y`.

Eщё пример: [Как убить поток в Питоне](https://stackoverflow.com/q/323972/4279) -- правильный ответ обязан упомянуть, что насильственно останавливать потоки это плохая идея (как это, например, java продемонстрировала), что лучше организовать код, чтобы  этого не требовалось и поток мог выйти сам по запросу или по завершению процесса. При этом, в дополнение, можно указать пути как реализовать нерекомендуемую опцию (с помощью pthread, Windows API или специализированного CPython C API в данном случае) -- большинству людей с подобным вопросом эти API вызовы не пригодятся, но для редких случаев, когда это оправдано, следует *как дополнение* привести буквальный ответ на вопрос.

Comment: `То есть в общем случае, на вопрос: «как сделать X, используя Y», вполне можно ответить «Y плохо подходит для X по причинам A,B,C, используйте Z вместо этого».` Я в подобных случаях обычно ограничиваюсь комментарием к вопросу -- там этим заметкам наилучшее место.

Comment: @AK это зависит от того насколько плохо Y подходит для задачи X. Если ситуация, когда использовать Y является хорошей идеей, является одна на миллион, то комментария маловато — комментарии предназначены для временной или второстепенной  информации — основная информация обязана быть в вопросах/ответах.