# Нормальны ли ответы с предложением использовать другую библиотеку/язык?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

Навеяно этим вопросом: [Как конвертировать в pdf фаил кирилическими символами в PhpWord?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/879798/15479)

Вопрос про PhpWord. В ответе говорится, что решился вопрос путём перехода на mPdf.

Для тех, кто с той же проблемой перейдёт из поисковика, вполне вероятно, такой ответ не подойдёт. Но сам по себе ответ проблему именно топикстартера решает.

Нормальны ли такие ответы, когда вопрос про одну библиотеку/язык/технологию, а в ответе совет про переход на другую?

Похожие обсуждения:

- [Уход от проблемы вместо её решения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3404/15479)

Comment: Если решает проблему, то вполне годится

Comment: «Как сделать прозрачное окно на PyGTK?» — «Держи пример с Qt5 на C++» — «Спасибо, перешёл на C++» 

Comment: @andreymal на самом деле, мне уже жаловались пользователи, когда вопрос про [tag:c], а им в ответе [tag:cpp] пихают. Так что, смех смехом, но проблема периодически всплывает.

Comment: Я считаю что да, но чаще всего должна быть хорошая аргументация почему именно следует менять в корне подход. Хотя ответы а вот "как вариант можно и так" тоже могут быть полезны, поэтому тут однозначного ответа, уверен, что не будет.

Comment: Мне кажется обсуждение лежит в области "проблемы молотка".

Comment: @Anamnian кстати, думал об этом же упомянуть в своём ответе, но что-то забыл :)

Answer (score 4):

Ответы могут быть как нормальны, так и не очень. Всё зависит от ситуации. Стоит вспомнить, что галочку на ответе (признак наиболее подходящего решения) ставит именно и только лишь автор вопроса. И если на подобном ответе стоит галочка — ответ однозначно уместен. Если ТС не жмакнул галочку просто так, значит проблему действительно удалось решить, а стало быть и другим посетителям такое решение может пригодиться. Но возможны и другие ситуации, когда появляется ответ вида «используйте А вместо В», и автору такого ответа дают понять (минусами и комментариями), что решение-то нужно именно для В. Чтобы таких (негативных) ситуаций избежать, мне кажется, будет достаточным до публикации ответа уточнить у автора вопроса, готов ли он всё же использовать А, и если готов, то смело дать ответ. При этом стоит дополнительно убедиться в правильности меток вопроса после полученного решения, возможно их придётся переназначить. Здесь главное, не попасть в ситуацию, когда кто-то пишет ответ в процессе переназначения меток. Как альтернативный вариант для исключения этой «гонки» ответов и меток, можно рассмотреть возможность задания нового вопроса (с подходящими метками) ТСом, или даже самоответа от участника, предложившего решение «используйте А вместо В».