# Как избежать буквальных ответов на очевидно неграмотные вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение

У меня есть вопрос, на который, как я уверен, ответа не существует, но иногда все равно очень хочется его задать.

По какой-то причине ответы на подобных ресурсах тяготеют к предельной буквальности. Вопрос очень часто рассматривается либо как персональный челендж для отвечающего, либо как вопрос на экзамене. При этом ни сам вопрос, ни предпосылки к его появлению никогда не подвергаются сомнению - отвечающий с жаром берется за решение в заданных рамках, не обращая внимание на то, что задача противоречит и здравому смыслу, и базовым принципам программирования.

В итоге чаще всего автору старательно и подробно помогают выстрелить себе в ногу.

Чаще всего в таких вопросах спрашивается, как нарушить тот или иной фундаментальный принцип архитектуры. То, что данный принцип *неизвестен автору* - понятно и простительно. Но по какой причине *отвечающие* принимают правила игры и стараются буквально ответить на вопрос, который очевидно не имеет смысла - для меня загадка.

Довольно частый пример такого вопроса в РНР - это "как перенумеровать первичный ключ "по порядку". Самое мерзкое, что отвечающие еще и высасывают из пальца оправдание своим буквальным ответам. Но никто при этом не объясняет несчастному новичку понятие уникального идентификатора. Никто не предлагает ему переименовывать его одноклассников каждый раз, когда они по-новому рассаживаются за партами, "чтобы все сидели по алфавиту". А все только стараются наперебой предложить решение заведомо бессмысленной и вредной задачи.

Свежий пример: [Как mysql update выполнить через время после запроса?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/596660/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-mysql-update-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0)

Люди, которые по определению знают принципы функционирования БД, любо отвечают сами на буквальный запрос автора, либо плюсуют ответы. Причем голоса здесь в какой-то мере значат даже больше чем ответы, показывая согласие сообщества в целом.

Учитывая принципы функционирования сайтов системы Stack Overflow (главное - не корректность информации и реальная помощь, а баллы и знаки), я не думаю что данную проблему как-то можно решить. Но честно говоря - очень хотелось бы.

Comment: 1) почему вы хотите лишить человека возможности выстрелить в ногу, если это его осознанное решение? 2) почему вы уверены, что приведенная информация в ответе не поможет другим читателям вопроса? 3) почему при этом, вы позволяете себе высказывать свою позицию, используя оскорбительные формулировки?

Comment: Вот именно эта остервенелая оппозиция "буквалистов" меня и удивляет больше всего.

Comment: @4per, если бы в комментарии не было третьего пункта, поставил бы ему плюс.

Comment: @Qwertiy, почему? неужели вы считаете оскорбительные высказывания приемлемыми? з.ы. впрочем, я искренне спрашивал автора, и вместо плюсов предпочел бы его ответы на вопросы.

Comment: @4per, потому что в данном контексте я не считаю это высказывание оскорбительным. Это вообще некое обобщение, не относящееся ни к кому конкретно, а значит никого и не оскорбляющее.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а вы о каком? я о том, которого, как сейчас узнал, уже нет. А было оно в комментариях в вопросе по ссылке.

Comment: @4per, я об исправлении, которое Nick Volynkin сделал в текущем вопросе подумал. Не про него было?

Comment: @Qwertiy,  нет про другое. А это я, среди тона заданного ещё на сайте, даже и не заметил.

Comment: @4per, значит, разобрались :)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Уход от проблемы вместо её решения](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3404/23044)

Answer (score 9):

Мне кажется, многие неопытные участники не знают, что возможно и что нет. Поэтому они и желают сломать архитектуру, они не знают, как нельзя. Примеров этому есть великое множество: у нас даже есть специальный термин для этого: [XY Problem](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/10105).

Плохой ответ будет потакать этим вопросам в надежде получить баллы от автора вопроса. Хороший ответ объяснит, почему подход автора неверен, и как нужно думать на самом деле (и в идеале получит много баллов от толковых участников).

Написать плохой ответ просто. Написать хороший ответ сложнее: придётся не только догадаться, что именно имел в виду ТС, но и объяснить проблему с более широкой перспективы. Кроме того, нужно вежливо, но твёрдо, не сильно раня нежные чувства неуверенных новичков, объяснить им их неправоту. Это не так уж и просто, особенно в более «массовых» отраслях программирования.

---

Принцип функционирования системы очень прост: это человеческая психология. Автору вопроса часто не хочется долго учиться, а хочется результат [сейчас и без усилий](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0). Это нормально. Плюсуют часто те, кто видит короткое решение, оно в их глазах выглядит предпочтительнее длинного текста. Но те, кто понимает, в чём дело, плюсуют длинный вдумчивый ответ.

---

Небольшое замечание по поводу персонального стиля (не воспримите как личную критику или придирки). Мне кажется, что вы иногда заявляете очевидные вещи слишком категорично. Те читатели, которые не знают этих вещей, сопротивляются психологически, и ставят минусы. Мне кажется, имеет смысл немного «подкрутить» уровень ответа к уровню аудитории, и даже простые вещи немного разжевать. Это будет полезно не только автору вопроса, но и тем, кто не большой специалист в вашей тематике, но хочет чему-то выучиться (например, мне).

Answer (score 9):

Вопросы на сайте существуют, чтобы другие люди, а не только автор могли найти ответ.

Поэтому ответ должен отвечать на вопрос как *написан*. Если я пришёл из поисковика по точным ключевым словам, я хочу ответ именно на этот вопрос.

В комментариях к вопросу или как часть ответа можно или даже *следует* упомянуть альтернативные интерпретации, особенно если вопрос может быть вызван частым заблуждением по теме.

К примеру ответ на вопрос "как с помощью regex изъять телефоны из HTML"  может упомянуть что это не лучшая идея и предложить использование настоящего HTML-парсера, но этот вопрос обязательно должен иметь ответ, показывающий (упоминая ограничения) буквальное (с regex) решение. Часто ввод регулярный и достаточно perl one-liner с regex запустить, чтобы результат получить, не создавая многострочную программу с формальным HTML-парсером.

> никогда не подвергаются сомнению

Это неверно. В *комментариях* или как *часть* ответа можно упомянуть и я видел как упоминают/лично упоминал альтернативные решения  к буквальному ответу.

Пример, один из самых знаменитых вопросов на SO: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/4279).

Связанный вопрос: [Answer what's asked, or answer what's desired? (2009)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18552/137096)

Answer (score 8):

Чувствуя камень в [свой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596714/191745) огород:)

**Во-первых**, обратите внимание на [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/596660/#comment805330_596660) под вопросом. Согласитесь, это хорошая попытка предоставить пользователю возможность изложить свою задачу в иной форме(переформулировать вопрос). Не захотел, значит не нужно/не хочет.

**Во-вторых**, я написал ответ, только **после** [просьбы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/596660/#comment805372_596687) показать пример со `sleep()`, что я и сделал.

**В-третьих**, мой ответ удовлетворяет условию задачи в вопросе. О том, почему это не стоит делать в принципе и так было понятно, но на всякий случай в ответе указал.

Поэтому ответ и был дан, хотя соглашусь, можно было и в комментариях написать, о чем я почему-то не сразу подумал(и вовсе не из-за зеленой галки или голоса).

На мой взгляд Вы слишком напрягаетесь, стоит подумать, что порой вопросы задаются не для применения на практике, а ради того костыля, о котором участник не смог додуматься самостоятельно. Просто потому, что он вдруг подумал "*возможно ли или не возможно?*" Это относится и к вопросу "*как перенумеровать первичный ключ*", несмотря на то, что такие вопросы вызывают недоумение, в т.ч. и у меня.

Я считаю правильным в таких случаях дать участнику ответ, но при это написать его минусы, почему не рекомендуется так делать и как лучше сделать. Почему ? Потому, что so - это место ответов на вопросы, где **каждый** может получить качественный ответ, если, конечно, это позволяют условия вопроса. Ответ "*глупый вопрос, учи основы*" не является качественным.

Лично я считаю плохими скорее ответы на вопросы-дубликаты, потому что уже есть ответ. Если же ответа нет, то стоит дать ответ и в дальнейшем подобные вопросы(с большой вероятностью хотя бы один такой же вопрос со временем возникнет) отмечать как дубликаты.

Просто *двигайтесь дальше, делая мир лучше своими ответами*.

---

А ответ на Ваш вопрос *Как избежать буквальных ответов на очевидно неграмотные вопросы?* - **в рамках всего сообщества практически никак**, стоит просто вежливо пояснить свою позицию автору ответа и если автор с Вами согласится, то в дальнейшем, возможно, будет на один комментарий больше и на один ответ меньше.

Comment: `Не захотел, значит не нужно/не хочет` — если не хочет задавать нормальный вопрос без проблемы XY, значит не должен получить ответов (т.е. вопрос следует закрыть). Мы обладаем знаниями и мы можем (и должны) диктовать свои условия того, как за этими знаниями обращаться. Можно считать это межчеловеческим API.

Comment: @NickVolynkin *если не хочет задавать нормальный вопрос без проблемы XY, значит не должен получить ответов* - да, если проблема не указана, слишком общая и т.п.. в данном случае автор задал конкретный вопрос "*Как mysql update выполнить через время после запроса?*" и привел пример своего запроса.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, в самом деле уверены в своих (наших) знаниях? (Это по поводу `вопрос следует закрыть`)

Comment: "Ответ *"глупый вопрос, учи основы"* не является качественным", да и ответом тоже не является. :)

Answer (score 4):

Можно выделить как минимум две основных задачи при написании ответа.

1. Дать конкретное практическое решение сформулированной задачи — то, что принесёт пользу прямо сейчас, но один раз.
2. Указать на правильный и комплексный путь решения этой и подобных задач, на лучшие практики и типичные ошибки, дать фундаментальное понимание системы. Это знание будет приносить пользу не сразу, понемногу, но долго — и суммарная польза будет больше.

Думаю, мы (активные участники, публикующие ответы) отлично справляемся с первой задачей, но часто недооцениваем важность второй. Однако, своими ответами мы не просто наполняем копилку решений, но и в значительной степени определяем то, как будет выглядеть разработка ПО в ближайшем будущем. Эти ответы реально влияют на популярность технологий и подходов, на качество архитектуры и кода, на взаимодействия и взаимопонимание между всеми, кто участвует в разработке ПО. Это одновременно отличная возможность что-то улучшить в своей отрасли и большая ответственность за будущее этой отрасли.

Мы здесь все немного технические евангелисты. Мы пишем о технологиях, в которых разбираемся, а рядом с каждым ответом стоит зелёная галочка и внушающее трепет число. Нам верят. Мы влияем на соотношение качества и взрывоопасных костылей в программах будущего — а будущее, вероятно, будет целиком и полностью зависеть от этих программ.

Давайте придавать бóльшее значение качеству, правильным подходам и долгосрочным перспективам.