# Подсказки о механиках работы Stack Overflow

Tags: поддержка

Stack Overflow — достаточно сложный сайт как технически, так и идеологически. Далеко не каждый новый участник сообщества, попав на сайт, с ходу понимает, как и зачем принимать ответы; что такое минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример; в чем отличие комментариев под вопросом от чата; как улучшить свой вопрос. В результате мы видим недопонимание и большое количество нарушений, что не может не вызывать ненужный шум и прения.

В модели Stack Overflow обучение «новичков» ложится на плечи более опытных участников. Чтобы сделать обучение более эффективным/автоматизированным, предлагаю собрать в этом вопросе небольшие ответы–подсказки о работе сайта.
(Обсуждение самой инициативы идет в вопросе [Как должны выглядеть подсказки о механиках сайта?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7022/))

#### Содержание

- [Как отблагодарить за ответ на Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7124/389694)
- [Отметьте ответ верным, получите +2](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7025/6).
- [Какие вопросы и ответы хорошие, а какие нет](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7374/389694)
- [Как пояснить или дополнить свой вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7027/389694)
- [Что такое чат?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7123/389694)
- [Мета: вопросы о модерации работе сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7122/389694)
- [Видео пояснение основных механик сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7021/6).

Answer (score 53):

## Как отблагодарить за ответ на Stack Overflow?

#### Задать новый интересный вопрос!

Лучшая благодарность — [задать еще один *интересный вопрос*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

[image]

Больше вопросов — больше доступных знаний для всех русскоязычных разработчиков.

#### Проголосовать «за» и принять ответ

Проголосуйте за ответ и его автор получит [+10 баллов репутации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3663/6). Если вопрос ваш, [примите ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7025/6), это даст еще [+15 репутации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7025/6) автору ответа.

[image]

Репутация дает участникам новые привилегии для управления сообществом, а это дополнительная *мотивация отвечать на ваши вопросы*.

#### Написать отзыв в социальных сетях

Социальные сети — лучшее место для того, чтобы сказать «Спасибо!» автору ответа. Расскажите друзьям и коллегам на своей страничке в социальной сети вашу историю — как вы задали вопрос и получили ответ на Stack Overflow на русском. Многие из ваших коллег именно в этот момент бьются над задачей уже более суток, не веря, что в Интернете можно получить квалифицированную помощь. Будьте для них положительным примером.

Ваши добрые слова про сайт и знатоков очень важны и нужны. Наш единственный способ развития — ваши рекомендации. Скажите «спасибо» — поделитесь информацией о сайте и его участниках с коллегами.

Answer (score 39):

## Отметьте ответ верным, получите +2

Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, который лучше всего решает вашу проблему, отметьте его «верным». Для этого:

1. Перейдите на страницу вопроса.
2. Найдите ответ, который помог вам решить проблему.
3. Нажмите на галку напротив выбранного ответа слева (сразу под стрелками голосования). После нажатия галка должна стать зеленой.

Отметить верным можно только один ответ в одном вопросе.

[image]

Отметив вопрос верным, вы получите 2 балла репутации, а все посетители сайта будут знать, какое решение сработало в вашем случае. Автор отмеченного вами ответа получит 15 баллов репутации, что мотивирует его отвечать вам в будущем.

Подробнее см. справку [Что это означает, если ответ «принят»?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)
 и «[Как работает репутация?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3663/)»

Answer (score 25):

## [~95% трафика из поисковиков на Stack Overflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources)

Задавая/отвечая на вопрос, стоит иметь в виду, что не только и не столько для автора вопроса существуют ответы на Stack Overflow. [Какими должны быть критерии оценки качества базы знаний?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044)

Если вопрос ясен и является типичной проблемой, то не важно сколько усилий автор вопроса приложил — важно насколько часто вопрос другие люди находят и насколько для них полезны ответы. [Работа за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044), [Следует ли закрывать все вопросы, в которых нет кода?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3851/23044)

[Не важно насколько прост вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/685/23044), если детальный ответ может помочь многим людям.

[Вопросы, закрытые как дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates), могут быть полезны, если они позволяют *поисковикам* направить людей к подходящему ответу. Разные люди одну и ту же проблему могут, используя самые разные слова, описывать.  Вопросы-дубликаты позволяют покрыть самые разные поисковые ключевые слова для проблемы, при этом собирая решения в одном месте.

Так как люди могут искать решения, используя неправильные термины, то не стоит вопросы изменять так, что это затруднит их последующий поиск для людей с похожей проблемой. [Следует ли править неинформативные заголовки вопросов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1381/23044)

То что человек из веб-поисковика пришёл, это ещё одна причина, по которой не стоит назад в поисковик отправлять, вместо того чтобы ссылку на решение/само решение опубликовать. [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/23044). Поисковик актуальные/рабочие ссылки возвращает, поэтому [ответ-ссылка не приветствуется](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1819/23044).

То что другие люди могут приземлится на вопросе, по конкретным ключевым словам, поощряет [буквальные ответы на вопрос (как он написан)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4144/23044). [Уход от проблемы вместо её решения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3404/23044).

Answer (score 22):

## Как пояснить или дополнить свой вопрос?

Если вы хотите дополнить вопрос, пояснить ситуацию, пожалуйста:

- НЕ создавайте ответ;
- НЕ публикуйте комментарий;
- НЕ задавайте новый вопрос.

Вместо этого:

- Перейдите на страницу вашего вопроса.
- Нажмите на ссылку «править», расположенную под метками вопроса:

[image]

- Добавьте два переноса строки и допишите всю необходимую информацию.
- Сохраните правку.

Answer (score 18):

## Не формат для Stack Overflow? Попробуй в чате!

Чат — это наше «[Третье место](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE)».

#### Когда использовать чат?

- Когда у вас есть вопрос, не подходящий для Stack Overflow по формату или теме.
- Когда вам надо динамично разрешить проблему.
- Когда вы хотите социализироваться в приятной дружеской атмосфере коллег–разработчиков.

#### Как перейти в чат?

- Через интерфейс сайта: В правом верхнем углу нажать на значок Stack Exchange и затем в появившимся меню на ссылку, ведущую на страницу списка чатов сообщества.

  [image]
- По прямой ссылке https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com
- Из боковой панели на Мете:

  [image]
- По ссылке из подвала любой страницы сайта:

  [image]

#### Популярные чаты сообщества:

- [Основной чат Stack Overflow на русском](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--)
- [Политота: Всевозможные политические баталии и демагогия на русском языке](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47216/ru-so)
- [Английский язык "для самых маленьких"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45075/)
- [Svg_chat: Talk about SVG (на русском)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat)
- [F#: Место для изучения и обучения](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f)
- [Дискуссии о C#/.NET на русском](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--)

#### Дополнительно:

- Привилегии для чатов:

  - [Общение в чатах (20 баллов баллов репутации)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat)
  - [Создавать чаты (100 баллов репутации)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms)
  - [Создавать чаты-витрины (1К баллов репутации)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms)

Answer (score 7):

## Есть вопрос о модерации или сайте? Задайте его на Мете!

Мета — это сайт вопросов и ответов о сайте и сообществе Stack Overflow.

#### О чем спрашивать на Мете?

Если вам не понятна механика работы сайта или у вас возник вопрос о модерации, идеологии или миссии, задайте его на Мете. Также на Мете мы публикуем [дефекты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82), [инициативы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), собираем [базу знаний о сайте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) и [дискутируем](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) о будущем сообщества.

#### Как перейти на Мету?

1. По прямой ссылке: [ru.meta.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/)
2. Через интерфейс сайта. В правом верхнем углу нажать на значок Stack Exchange и затем в появившимся меню на ссылку, ведущую на Мету:

   [image: Как попасть на Мету]

На текущий момент, чтобы задать вопрос на Мете [вам необходимо иметь 5 баллов репутации на основном сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta).

#### Дополнительно:

- [Что такое Мета и как она работает?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 6):

## Посмотреть видео как работает Stack Overflow

[image]

Основной вопрос: «[Справка Stack Overflow в видео формате](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4191/6)».