# Как я могу узнать, какие пробелы есть у меня по некоторым темам?

Tags: обсуждение

На ruSO я задал вопрос о том, правильно ли я изложил в общем тему, и что я упустил. Прибежал человек и сказал, что вопрос неправилен и стоит удалить тему. Куда мне стоит задавать вопросы такого рода? Или на ruSO такое не принято, и мне придется идти на другой форум?

Comment: Не думаю, что [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/982258/178988) надо удалять или закрывать.

Comment: Восстановил. Просто вполне могло оказаться, что это правда запрещено.

Comment: @Qwertiy https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: @Suvitruf Тут уже вопрос в том, можно ли задавать вопросы типа "Я не хочу научиться неправильно, укажите на возможные недостатки и проблемы".

Comment: @Qwertiy Пожалуйста, аргументируйте, почему это не надо закрывать? Вопросы вида двести-в-одном? Чтобы каждый пользователь приходил и создавал "свою" ветку, в которой он дописывал очередные двести вопросов? Нам такой хоккей не нужен! Мне попался этот вопрос в очереди проверок и я проголосовал за его закрытие.

Comment: В таких случаях нужно как можно подробнее расписать конкретную ситуацию. Общего рецепта для любых тем нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, надо закрывать, как минимум 3-4 дубликатами.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Поставьте себя на место отвечающих и подумайте, будут ли они читать и разбирать сочинение в 10 страниц на тему "Мое понимание ООП в Java". Я очень склоняюсь к тому, что для большинства ответ - "нет". Stack Overlow - сайт для конкретных вопросов, а не для обучения. Форумы - для обсуждений, но обширные темы не приветствуются и там. Хотите проверить свои знания - найдите сайт с онлайн-тестами или, в конце концов, купите вузовский учебник, в котором есть раздел "задания для самопроверки", и прорешайте их все. Куда больше толку будет, чем спрашивать здесь или на форумах.

Comment: Вы правы. Однако есть много микромоментов, создавать же новый вопрос для каждого - не комильфо. В данной ситуации же - признаю, я включил даже то, что уже обсудил на форуме(мой косяк). Однако я за выкладывание микромоментов в одном вопросе. У меня цель - изучить ВСЮ теорию, а потом приступать к практике. Я должен знать все нюансы, чтобы не приучаться писать "говнокод". Только через полное понимание мы сможем построить коммунизм :D

Comment: Не надо учить ВСЮ теорию. Г..нокод можно писать как зная всю теорию, так и не зная - это ортогональные вещи. Не надо писать один бесконечный вопрос с перечислением всего что вы знаете до мельчайших нюансов - пишите конкретные. Вы думаете у вас так много вопросов будет? Чтобы суметь выжать из себя сто вопросов - нужно очень сильно постараться. Это только кажется, что спрашивать легко.

Comment: @Miron а еще за 100 интересных вопросов, заданных в разные дни, тут дают знак [«Сократ»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/89/socratic)

Comment: @A_K если я буду знать всю теорию, то смогу хорошо спроектировать программу. Избегу говнокода на этом этапе (если реально всё пойму). А если "чистый код" прочитаю и буду следовать этим нормам, то вообще красиво будет. А сочесть это с интеллектом и полным пониманием, то говнокоду не просочиться.

Comment: @Miron еще как просочиться. У вас не будет "не говнокода" без практики. Скорее всего без долгой практики. Ах да, еще чтобы не писать г-код нужно достаточно хорошо знать паттерны, чтобы не писать лишнего и велосипедов.

Answer (score 6):

Если быть точным, я сказал, что "[Мое изложение темы классов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/982258/1)" - это вообще не вопрос. Важно понимать, что Stackoverflow - это не форум, а Q&A-сервис, принципы его использования существенно отличаются. В понимании может помочь чтение [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help), просмотр [вводного видео](https://youtu.be/PpTqzVGPLQY) и ответы к [этому вопросу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7020/204271). В частности, если вы внимательно прочитаете раздел "[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)", "[На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" и "[Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)" справки, то сможете насчитать в своём "вопросе" не менее 5 проблем.

Comment: В ruSO давно пора добавить cookbook

Comment: @DaemonHK [он был](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation), но не выстрелил.

Comment: Ну, если он был в формате Q&A в его стандартном исполнении, то неудивительно

Comment: @DaemonHK, там не совсем Q&A было