# Как на Stack Overflow узнать количество новых вопросов со времени последнего посещения?

Tags: поддержка

Захожу на Stack Overflow от случая к случаю, но хочу быть в курсе последних событий.
Однако это проблематично, так как непонятно, сколько новых вопросов пришло со времени моего последнего посещения.
Нет ли где-то на сайте такой информации?

И еще в продолжении темы.
Нет ли на сайте информации, какой самый ранний вопрос я просматривал последним в мое предыдущее посещение?
Это помогло бы мне не листать лишнее при поиске места, на котором я окончил просматривать вопросы в прошлый раз.

Answer (score 6):

Если вы просто открыли главную страницу или смотрели какие-то ответы без комментирования, голосования, добавления вопросов в избранное, то узнать, что есть новое, а что было старое средствами сайта не представляется возможным.

Предложение добавить подобный функционал было отклонено на MSE: [Add a "recently viewed" tab in the user account page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67675/339911).

Стоит заметить, что возможность иметь список просмотренных ранее вопросов есть в мобильном приложении [Stack Exchange для iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8). Правда этот список вряд ли будет синхронизирован между разными устройствами.

Время посещения сайта в прошлый раз можно также посмотреть в истории браузера, которым вы пользуетесь. А далее использовать [поиск сообщений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) с учетом этой даты.

Чтобы данные были переносимы между разными клиентами, достаточно как-то отметиться на сайте, самое простое: добавить вопрос в избранное. Такие вопросы видны на соответствующей [вкладке активности участника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=favorites) (можно использовать разную сортировку, например, по дате добавления в избранное). Список других выполненных ранее действий доступен участнику (да и всем остальным в силу публичности взаимодействия с сайтом) на странице активности в [соответствующей вкладке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=all).

Comment: Пользоваться меткой избранное для отмечания места последнего посещения невозможно. Так как метка избранное показывает собственно вопрос, а не место вопроса в ленте вопросов.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 так можно добавить в избранное свежий вопрос, этим зафиксируете время последнего просмотра. А дальше можно на это время опираться в поиске. Правда, вопрос могут удалить ;)

Answer (score 5):

Эта информация доступна в самых разных форматах, смотря какая цель в вашем случае.

К примеру, если ничего не делать, а просто *оставить страницу браузера открытой*, то количество новых для выбранного вида вопросов автоматически отображается. К примеру, откройте вкладку с [текущими вопросами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tab=active). Если вы отошли от компьютера, то вернувшись через несколько минут вы можете увидеть надпись: «Новая активность в X вопросах». Если вы нажмёте на эту надпись, то обновлённые вопросы подгрузятся.

Если вам *удобней с RSS работать*, то есть [«лента новых вопросов»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/feeds). На Stack Overflow на русском задаётся [порядка 200 вопросов в день](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday). Уже через неделю более тысячи новых вопросов будет. Если у вас вопросы, только по избранным метками интересуют, к примеру [вопросы о подноготной работы кода, написанного на Питоне.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-internals), то существует соответствующая [лента новых вопросов с меткой [python-internals]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=python-internals&sort=newest) (можно и любые другие метки использовать).

Если есть желание, вы можете [подписаться на получение вопросов по *электронной почте*](https://stackexchange.com/users/7098884/pepsicoca1?tab=subscriptions).

> хочу быть в курсе последних событий

Если не нужны все вопросы, то некоторая подборка публикуется в [*twitter*](https://twitter.com/rustackoverflow). Поищите, может есть присутствие на  социальных сетях, если вы ими пользуетесь.

Ваш браузер, мобильное приложение запоминают какие страницы/вопросы вы посещали.

Интересные вам вопросы можно найти с помощью *встроенного поиска*. К примеру, чтобы найти текущие вопросы по меткам, в которых вы отвечали на вопросы: [intags:mine is:q](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aq). Есть [*Гугл поиск* по всем SE сайтам](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD). Существуют такие вещи как [Google Alerts](https://www.google.ru/alerts), чтобы новые результаты автоматически присылались.

Более специфичные запросы можно выполнять используя [*Data.SE*](http://data.stackexchange.com/). К примеру, чтобы [найти сообщения, которые были обновлены после вашего комментария](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/334495/posts-with-activity-after-your-last-comment?UserId=192421).

Существует *официальное API*, которое позволяет не только читать, но и программно выполнять действия от имени пользователя на сайте (https://stackapps.com/). К примеру, [Как смотреть пришло тебе сообщение или ответ в ru.stackoverflow.com через requests](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/729167/23044).

Comment: Не надо уповать  на браузер. Устройства могут быть разные. Есть домашний комп, есть рабочий комп и у всех разная история браузера. Вы еще посоветуйте таскать историю браузера с компа на комп. Всего-то делов добавить одну запись в профиль пользователя и проблема решена. Было бы о чем разговаривать. Тем более, что вопрос уже поднимался.

Comment: @pepsicoca1: если вы пытаетесь сказать "спасибо, что уделили время, чтобы рассказать какие опции есть для заданной задачи", то у вас плохо получается :) Как, когда и какие из этих опций использовать и имеет ли смысл их вообще использовать -- это для разных людей и ситуаций по-разному -- ответы на Stack Overflow не только и не столько для автора вопроса (это не help-desk).  Кстати, *если* вы хотите свою историю посещений посмотреть на разных устройствах, то у браузера есть функция синхронизации, ничего таскать не надо.

Comment: [...если вы хотите...] Я хочу, чтобы нужная функциональность была реализована явно. И не хочу многословных объяснений что мне это не нужно. Или не менее многословных объяснений как выкрутиться из очередного тупичка. Тем более что выяснилось, что вопрос уже поднимался. То есть в наличии не один сумасшедший которых хочет странного, а группа пользователей, которым это надо.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 в комментариях не стоит новую функциональность предлагать. Чтобы отслеживать статус предложения, можете попробовать новое сообщение с меткой [tag:предложение] опубликовать ("как узнать кол-во новых вопросов" не является синонимом "добавьте «недавно просмотренные» вкладку"). На [большом Stack Overflow эту функциональность отклонили](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67675) (ссылка из ответа @alexolut), но для других (меньших) сообществ вы можете изложить зачем оно надо (какие проблемы решает), чем конкретно не хватает существующих возможностей.

Answer (score 2):

Ох, я сейчас наловлю минусов: вы спрашиваете, как сделать то-то, а я [хочу вас отговорить от этого](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/213987).

На so обычно ищут ответ на свой конкретный вопрос. Есть те, кто следит за определенной меткой, это чаще завсегдатаи сайта.

Если вы находитесь в режиме 'читаю so каждый день', то самый простой совет: держите открытой вкладку с вашей любимой меткой или метками. (Лучше всего переключить именно на вид 'новые вопросы', а не обновления вопросов). Будете видеть новые вопросы, а редактирование не будет подымать вопрос наверх. По мере поступления новых вопросов число непрочитанных будет видно в уведомлении, можно кликнуть и открыть последние вопросы.

А если вы читаете so от случая к случаю, то и нечего читать вопросы с последнего посещения. Честно. Читайте свежие, их снова наберётся множество.
Вы *ничего* не потеряете, если пропустите день или неделю. Следите за тем, что в эфире, а старое пусть уходит в историю -- для тех, кто ищет конкретные ответы.

Не верите? )) Войдите в режим чтения so каждый день и вы быстро это заметите.

В общем, как говорят в чате такой кейс *не нужен*. Я бы тоже отклонил подобный фичереквест.