# Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, вопросы-по-метке

Как задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например:  по `Pandas` / `Numpy` / `SciPy` / `SciKit Learn` / `SQL` / etc.) так, чтобы:

1. вопрос был правильно понят
2. получить наиболее эффективный (производительный) ответ
3. получить правильный ответ как можно быстрее
4. не получать "минусы" за вопрос

Comment: Только это на Мету

Comment: @Nofate, по-моему это слишком узконаправленный вопрос для `Meta`... Это по конкретным библиотекам... В англоязычной версии SO этот вопрос на `Meta` переносить не стали...

Comment: «как задавать вопросы на сайте вопросов» это хрестоматийный, по словарю мета-вопрос. «Как сгруппировать dataframe по столбцу»—не мета. «Как задать вопрос о том как сгруппировать dataframe по столбцу»—100% мета. На сколько узок или широк вопрос не имеет значения. Может быть широкий не мета-вопрос, может быть узкий мета-вопрос—это ортогональные понятия.

Comment: @MaxU, не думаю, что надо создавать на мете метки по языкам программирования и фреймвёркам.

Comment: @Qwertiy, это одна из причин - почему я создал этот вопрос на сайте для программистов, но его перенесли сюда. :( Этот вопрос специфичный для модулей для обработки и анализа данных

Comment: @MaxU, это понятно, но другие вопросы [metatag:вопросы-по-метке] вполне обходятся без лишних меток. Думаю, текстовый поиск и так хорошо всё найдёт. А метки языков на мете скорее лишние. Ну и всё равно метка, использующаяся только на одном вопросе, через полгода (кажется) автоматически удалится.

Comment: @Qwertiy, лично мое мнение - этот вопрос более уместен на сайте для программистов ([тот же самый вопрос в англоязычной версии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)). Но, на ru.stackoverflow.com, похоже свои правила, которые отличаются от stackoverflow.com ...

Comment: @MaxU: то что на английская версия не была отмигрирована, это вероятно просто баг (сейчас уже поздно мигрировать). Тема достаточно непротиворечивая: вопросы о программировании—на основном сайте, а вопросы о том как задавать вопросы на сайте вопросов/ответов по программированию принадлежат Мете. И на ru.SO и [en]SO принято обсуждать вопросы о работе сайта, как им пользоваться, какие правила и соглашения именно на Мете.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Чтобы правильно задать вопрос надо приложить немало усилий.](https://unhandled-exception.ru/others/books/verniy-vopros/)

Сначала ознакомьтесь с общими рекомендациями:

- ["Как задать хороший вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- ["Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

---

[Данный вопрос и ответы на него в англоязычной версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

*Кратко* опишите задачу (проблему). Не надо писать "сочинение" о том как вы хотите обработать данные и что получить на выходе, описывая это "сухим" текстом без примеров.

Гораздо лучше и понятнее будет привести пример исходных данных и то что вы хотите получить на выходе. В большинстве случаев достаточно взглянуть на исходную и "выходную" матрицу, чтобы понять что автор вопроса хочет получить. С описанием словами (без примеров входных и *особенно* выходных данных) - это, скорее, редкость.

Все указанные в вопросе модули (библиотеки) предназначены для обработки данных,
поэтому постарайтесь привести в вопросе небольшой (3-6 строк [элементов в случае одномерных данных] обычно более чем достаточно) воспроизводимый пример данных на входе и то что вы хотите получить на выходе.

Пример данных должен помочь воспроизвести проблему.

*Вы же не хотите получить ответ, который будет идеально работать для данных, которые вы привели в качестве примера, но который не будет работать для ваших реальных данных?*

Поэтому убедитесь, что вы можете воспроизвести проблему, используя данные из вашего примера.

Данные часто содержат конфиденциальную информацию - такую информацию надо замаскировать. Вместо реальных имен, адресов и т.д. обычно подойдут `"Name111"`, `"Address213"` и т.п.

Данные лучше всего приводить в виде Python кода, чтобы сэкономить время тем, кто захочет ответить на ваш вопрос.
Примеры:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# простой пример 
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

np.random.seed(123)  #  для генерации воспроизводимых значений

# пример создания DataFrame со случайными данными различных типов
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    # some ways to create random data
    'a':np.random.randn(6),
    'b':np.random.choice( [5,7,np.nan], 6),
    'c':np.random.choice( ['panda','python','shark'], 6),
    # some ways to create systematic groups for indexing or groupby
    # this is similar to r's expand.grid(), see note 2 below
    'd':np.repeat( range(3), 2 ),
    'e':np.tile(   range(2), 3 ),
    # a date range and set of random dates
    'f':pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=6, freq='D'),
    'g':np.random.choice( pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=365, 
                          freq='D'), 6, replace=False) 
    })
```

выдаст:

```
          a   b       c  d  e          f          g
0 -1.085631 NaN   panda  0  0 2011-01-01 2011-08-12
1  0.997345   7   shark  0  1 2011-01-02 2011-11-10
2  0.282978   5   panda  1  0 2011-01-03 2011-10-30
3 -1.506295   7  python  1  1 2011-01-04 2011-09-07
4 -0.578600 NaN   shark  2  0 2011-01-05 2011-02-27
5  1.651437   7  python  2  1 2011-01-06 2011-02-03
```

В крайнем случае пример данных можно привести в виде содержимого CSV файла или в таком виде, чтобы их можно было легко прочитать, используя [`df = pd.read_clipboard()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html) - обязательно убедитесь, что вы сами можете прочитать эти данные при помощи [pd.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) или [pd.read_clipboard()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html)

Также можно выложить файл(ы) с примером данных на любом [свободном (и не требующем регистрации) файлообменнике](https://www.google.com/search?q=free+file+%28%7Eupload%7C%7Eexchange%7C%7Eshare%29+no+registration). Особенно это актуально когда для воспроизведения проблемы надо привести файл в оригинальной кодировке и/или в бинарном формате (например Excel, PDF, etc.). StackOverflow пока? не позволяет прикреплять файлы (за исключением изображений) к сообщениям.

**Как делать не надо:** - приводить пример данных, код или вопрос в виде картинки / фотографии / скриншота.

Часто задающие вопрос приводят пример данных в виде скриншота или даже фотографии - конечно это удобно для того, кто задает вопрос.

В самом лучшем случае вы получите непроверенный ответ. Вряд ли кто-нибудь захочет "вбивать" информацию с вашей картинки, чтобы проверить правильность ответа на вопрос.

Чаще всего люди, знающие ответ просто пройдут мимо, т.к. в большинстве случаев это обернется потерей времени впустую и комментариями наподобие:

- ваш код не работает
- ваш код содержит ошибку "XYZ"
- я не это имел(а) в виду
  и т.д.

Задумайтесь **для чего вы задаете вопрос?**

Хотите ли вы получить ответ в принципе? Хотите ли вы получить проверенный (протестированный) ответ?

Не даром в кругу людей, занимающихся обработкой данных, циркулирует [популярная цитата, впервые озвученная (c) профессором Edwin R. Fisher](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2017/12/29/god-data/):

> **"In God we trust, others must provide data."**

PS случается, что автор вопроса "зациклен" на решении, которое представляется ему единственно возможным. В этом случае он формулирует вопрос так, что даже получив ответ на этот вопрос - это не поможет ему решить изначальную проблему.
Это называется ["Ошибка микроскопа-молотка" или "Ошибка XY"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy) - если вам намекнули на это в комментариях, вы можете значительно улучшить ваш вопрос, прояснив изначальную проблему (не забывайте о примерах!).

Comment: С благодарностью приму правки ответа, если замечены ошибки в тексте... :)

Comment: ссылки на `[ask]` и `[mcve]` стоит упомянуть: [ask], [mcve]

Comment: @jfs, да, имеет смысл добавить - спасибо

Comment: как по мне ответ подходит для любого языка программирования, но с примерами на `python`