# Является ли хорошим вопрос вида "Зачем нужен X в языке Y"?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, очередь-проверок

Недавно делал ревью, наткнулся на вопрос: [Для чего в Python 3.8 вводят новый оператор :=?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/854267)

Весь текст вопроса:

> Что он делает? Для чего он нужен?

Я уже потянулся к кнопке "закрыть вопрос", но рука дрогнула, и я нажал "Выглядит нормально". Каково же было мое удивление, когда я увидел

> [image: скриншот]

Мало того, что он неимоверно заплюсован, так его еще и в пример ставят, как хороший вопрос. "А еще боремся за почетное звание дома высокой культуры и быта" (с). Может, как-то фильтровать эталонные вопросы и ответы?

**UPD**

Вот цитата из справки ([Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)):

> Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа. Поделитесь результатом вашего поиска и расскажите, что вы нашли и почему найденные ответы вас не устроили. Это продемонстрирует вашу способность думать самостоятельно, поможет избежать повторяющихся очевидных ответов и, самое важное, увеличит шансы на получение точного ответа!

Вот всплывающая подсказка, которая появляется, когда вы наводите мышку на стрелочку вверх у вопроса:

> Вопрос отражает стремление разобраться; он понятен и несёт пользу

Я не считаю, что сабжевый вопрос соответствует этим критериям.

Comment: А почему вы решили, что этот вопрос плох?

Comment: Так вопрос и есть хороший.

Comment: А, ну ОК. Значит, я просто ничего не понимаю в вопросах и ответах по программированию.

Comment: Просто для меня это показатель, что автор вопроса программирует, не приходя в сознание. Google-driven development в чистом виде.

Comment: @Dmitry на SO больше всего людей приходит из поисковиков. И многие из них лишь начинают познавать азы программирования.

Comment: И задача SO - дать им понять, что всегда найдутся люди, готовые вытирать им сопли и жевать за них морковку, надо только поискать? Не, спасибо, я в этом не участвую.

Comment: @Dmitry да вас вроде никто и не заставляет отвечать на такие вопросы.

Comment: @Dmitry а касательно очереди проверок - это нормально, даже если бы вы не прошли проверку. Каждый имеет своё мнение/взгляды, которые могут не совпадать с системой.

Comment: @Suvitruf 1. Дело не в том, кто меня заставляет. Дело в том, какие вопросы система выдает за эталонные. 2. Вы врете, у меня нет права на собственное мнение (и вы не можете этого не знать). Если я называю этот вопрос плохим, система сообщает, что я не прошел проверку. Несколько таких ошибок (там совсем мало надо) - и система блокирует на время возможность делать ревью. Или за последние пару лет что-то изменилось?

Comment: @Dmitry я на такую блокировку не попадал, хоть и фейлил часто првоерку.

Comment: Да? Ну извините тогда. Повезло, значит. Я попадал неоднократно на enSO, причем там все еще хуже - там иногда противоречивые требования попадаются. Натыкаешься на ответ в одну строчку - нажимаешь "ОК" - "Ошибка, это сообщение низкого качества, его нужно было удалить". Ревьюишь дальше. Через пару дней опять ответ в одну строчку - "Удалить" - "Ошибка, это качественный ответ" (у него, допустим, 100+ плюсов) - "ай-ай-ай, вы сделали слишком много ошибок, приходите через неделю". Я сначала даже копил ссылки, хотел им телегу накатать, а потом махнул рукой. Не похоже, чтобы им там было интересно.

Comment: У вопроса 2 ответа, один из которых принят. Вопрос предельно ясен, энциклопедичен, полезен. В чём смысл его закрытия?

Comment: @Dmitry, это, конечно же мое мнение (не совпадающее с официальным), но смысл существования SO как раз в том, чтобы можно было **оперативно** получать ответы на **любые IT** вопросы (или по крайней мере толковые отсылки в гугл). Лично я уверен, что в принципе могу найти ответ на любой вопрос и без SO, однако часто значительно эффективней спросить и может через час-другой уже получить ответ. Так и с этим вопросом, все нормально. Если вам что-то в простых вопросах (без сомнения освещенных в документации по языку) не нравится, то просто проходите мимо, не стесняйтесь

Comment: Многие люди не собирают макулатуру из самоучителей и т.д., а просто учатся правильно задавать вопросы в поисковой системе. На моём личном опыте получение исчерпывающего ответа с примерами или годным описанием на порядок быстрее чем из какого-то мануала. И, замечу, SO уже в половине случаев первоисточник получения ответа. Так что вы тут неправы. Даже такие банальные вещи иногда требуются новичку чтобы понять смысл кода который у него перед глазами не прибегая к многочасовым посиделкам за книгой.

Comment: слова основателя сайта: «Stack Overflow: None of Us is as Dumb as All of Us»

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR - вопрос может казаться "так себе", но он притягивает хорошие ответы.

---

Данный энциклопедический вопрос действительно достаточно низкого качества (т.е. автор не приложил усилий к поиску информации от слова совсем), но это перевешивается с лихвой тем, что у вопроса отличный энциклопедичный ответ.

Если рассматривать вопрос и ответ вместе, то они составляют очень достойную пару, в которой есть вся полезная информация для других посетителей интересующихся темой.

Что можно было бы сделать - улучшить вопрос, добавив ему немного контекста, цитату со ссылки.

---

Касательно общего вопроса "Зачем нужен X в Y”, это перекликается с [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709). Т.е. вопрос не о том как что-то сделать (забить гвоздь), а о том, что еще можно делать инструментом (молотком, например выправлять вмятины или использовать как рычаг). Но с другой стороны, знание возможностей инструмента, позволяет гораздо лучше понять его и эффективнее использовать.

Comment: полезность вопроса измеряется не усилиями автора, количеством людей, которым помог ответ на него. [Работа за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044)

Answer (score 11):

1. У вопроса много просмотров. Он полезный.
2. У вопроса однозначный ответ.

Что в нём плохого? Или придирка именно к "эталонности"?

Comment: Поддерживаю. Вопросы, зачем нужен "x" в языке "y" нужны тем кто самостоятельно изучают яп. Эти вопросы генерят трафик стэку, если их не будет сдесь они всплывут на другом сайте.