# Допустимы ли ответы "Не надо это делать, лучше <другой способ>"?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, правила

Недавно один участник дал ответ в стиле:

> Не надо делать так. Лучше используйте <что-то другое>. <и как использовать>.

Я его пометил "не является ответом" и поспорил немного в комментах по-поводу таких ответов. Модераторы отметили тревогу верной, а ответ снесли. И я считаю, что такие ответы недопустимы.

Но хотелось бы услышать мнение сообщества ;)

Comment: На мой субъективный взгляд, не допустимы, но модераторы вроде обычно обычно считают такое не «не ответом», а «неверным ответом» и оставляют на растерзание сообществу

Comment: `Не стоит отвечать просто «не делай этого», следует добавить «попробуй вместо этого сделать следующее» — предложите достойную альтернативу. Любой ответ, который направляет спрашивающего в нужное русло, является ценным.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Да, разумеется.

Хороший отвечающий поймёт, в чём настоящая проблема автора вопроса. Он подскажет не одноразовое решение частной проблемы, а объяснит, как правильно думать, чтобы подобная проблема не возникала. Если автор вопроса думает неправильно, то ему надо помочь и направить на правильный путь. Ответ «на этом пути хорошего решения нет» — очень хороший и ценный ответ.

Почему нужно не доверять тексту вопроса? Дело в том, что для формулировки хорошего вопроса необходимо знать половину ответа, а значит, неопытные участники не в состоянии задать правильный вопрос. Они пробуют наиболее очевидный путь, и спрашивают как сделать следующий шаг. А значит, автор вопроса и правда часто не знает, что ему *на самом деле* нужно.

Вот примеры.

1. Как правильно использовать `mysqli_real_escape_string` для данных, введённых пользователем[?](https://bobby-tables.com/)  Правильный ответ — никак, используйте prepared statement + placeholder[.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422165/10105)
2. Как вытащить данные из HTML, какая регулярка лучше[?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/276994) Правильный ответ — не морочьте себе голову и используйте нормальный парсер[.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420355/10105)

В каждом из этих примеров формально данный правильный ответ скорее не поможет автору вопроса (а также будущим читателям), а навредит, т. к. они будут думать, что с избранным ими методом никаких проблем нету.

Хороший ответ не отвечает формально правильно на неправильно поставленный вопрос, он делает так, чтобы последующие вопросы отпали.

---

Другое дело, что этим принципом не следует злоупотреблять. На вопрос «как сделать цикл в batch-файле» ответ «переходите на Linux» был бы неуместен.

---

Подобная тема уже всплывала несколько лет тому назад: [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/10105)

Comment: Вот-вот, регулярки -- это просто бич какой-то, постоянно любят спрашивать ([например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3)), как ту или иную регулярку написать, чтобы теги попарсить.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что тема про «Ошибку молотка» предлагает отредактировать вопрос, а вовсе не давать ответ

Comment: @andreymal: Я бы всё же предложил не редактировать вопрос, т. к. подобная XY-проблема может быть у многих, и пусть они приходят из поисковика в именно ответ, объясняющий, какой именно X нужен вместо искомого Y.

Comment: @andreymal, только там просят не поменять вопрос, а дополнить информацией о конечной цели.

Answer (score 5):

Да, такие ответы допустимы.

Вопрос может быть задан как угодно и если в нём не оговаривается что-то, что должно исключить такой способ, то ответ с более правильным решением допустим и даже желателен.

> - Как правильно забивать гвозди микроскопом?
> - Используй для этого молоток.

Нормальный ответ, или будем разрешать только чтобы кто-то про микроскоп расписал?

Comment: Как же так — это же комментарий, не ответ. В вашем примере еще ладно, но как насчет "Как найти сумму всех чисел в массиве на питоне?", ответ: "лучше напиши на жаве: `code`". Разве это не тоже самое?

Comment: Но ведь этот ответ не объясняет, как же всё-таки забивать гвозди именно микроскопом... Я не считаю такие ответы ответами

Comment: @andreymal Я тоже.

Comment: Должно быть пояснение, почему способ не подходит. В приведенном примере этого нету, только бездоказательное "не надо так". Пример с молотком здесь не сильно помогает на самом деле, в ПО чаще куда менее очевидно, почему подход выбран неправильно. Если нет желания объяснять, лучше не браться писать ответ, как мне кажется.