# Что следует писать при правке вопроса в ее описании?

Tags: поддержка, правки

Многие вопросы, нуждающиеся в правке - часто их задают новички, но не всегда - содержат простейшие пунктуационные, или орфографические, или просто речевые ошибки, которые затрудняют понимание вопроса. Из некоторых вопросов приходится удалять такие фразы как `Здравствуйте`, `Я только новичок`, `Надеюсь на помощь`, `Вопрос собственно в следующем:`, и т.п.

При правке вопроса, снизу, нужно обязательно (если еще нет 2000реп.) указать т.н. «Описание правки». Так вот, что в нем нужно писать? Насколько я понимаю, модераторы и участники с большим кол-вом рейтинга сразу видят и описание правки и саму правку. Тогда зачем каждый раз описывать `Подправил  вопрос`, `Удалил повторяющиеся слова`, `Поправил ссылки` и так далее, если проверяющие это **итак** увидят, они **итак** будут проверять правильно ли я поправил ссылки или неправильно, были там действительно повторяющиеся слова или не были?

Или, возможно, в описании правки нужно писать что-то другое, чего я пока не догоняю?

Comment: По идее, при правке ответов, точно такие же условия

Answer (score 5):

Обычно все это описание игнорируют, так как в подавляющем большинстве случаев, правки тривиальны и сами за себя говорят. Описание действительно нужно для сложных или запутывающих случаев - например:

- ТС привел код по ссылке, а вы его перенесли в тело вопроса/ответа
- Вы поменяли форматирование, чтобы отображалось что-то, что было из-за него неправильно скрыто. Т.к. при проверка идет показ сообщений в трех режимах на выбор проверяющего, в некоторых из них может показаться, что текст допридуман (а не вынесен, например, из альта картинки)
- Вы добавили уточнения в вопрос из комментария ТС к одному из ответов (которого при проверке не видно)
- Вы обсудили что-то с ТС в чате, и (по его просьбе) переписали вопрос/ответ "как надо"
- Вы сильно изменили вопрос, чтобы решить [проблему XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709) и привести его в соответствие данным ответам
- Вы изменили ответ, сохранив его суть, но упростив или значительно расширив необходимые, на ваш взгляд, части
- и т.п.

Стоит заметить, что описания правок читают не только их принимающие (если у вас меньше 2000реп. и вы предлагаете правки), но и сам автор вопроса/ответа - ему может быть непонятно что и зачем вы поменяли, если изменение нетривиально.

TLDR: Простым правкам описание обычно не нужно. Если правка нетривиальна - описание помогает её обосновать для проверяющих и для автора вопроса/ответа.

Comment: Спасибо, а как расшифровываются ТС и ХУ?

Comment: @МаксимФисман ТС (топик-стартер, автор вопроса), [XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/176217).