# Почему минусуют мой технический вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение

Задал вопрос про конкретную ситуацию с ограничением по ключам для объекта javascript.

[Как убрать лимит на количество ключей у объекта javascript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1349042/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-javascript)

На этот вопрос должен быть дан конкретный ответ, с дополнительными комментариями если требуется. Зачем заниматься оффтопом и выяснением не связанных с темой вопросов?
В английской версии сайта stackoverflow как правило дается вариант решения с развернутым ответом и описываются какие либо недостатки такого подхода.

А тут попытка вывести тему в оффтоп, и большое количество не имеющих ценности комментариев. В итоге на вопрос не дан ответ, и выставляются минусы.

Comment: Мне кажется вопрос по ссылке не заслуживает минусов. Тем не менее, сам вопрос достаточно странный и очень сильно похож на проблему молотка (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709). В заплюсованных комментариях вам верно на это указали, а в ответ вы, как-будто бы, огрызаетесь - *"Интересуют ответы **по теме** от людей **которые разбираются** в javascript"* (выделение моё).

Comment: А смысл уводить тему в оффтоп? Использование других инструментов или подхода это уже другая тема. В английской версии сайта дается ответ в котором указываются недостатки этого подхода. Тут получается другой подход? 
И в одном из комментариев участник Alexey Ten пишет "Живите с этим."
В чем ценность подобных комментариев?

Comment: На мой взгляд, смысл комментариев (удаленных), был в том, чтобы наоборот помочь вам тему вывести из оффтопа, конкретизировать из абстрактной, в прикладную/полезную. А то сейчас вопрос сродни "я накачиваю колесо на тачке до 11 атмосфер, а дальше не идет .. как поднять давление?".

Comment: В том то и дело, что тема не абстрактная, а конкретная. С конкретным техническим решением и ответом. И беда в том, что сильные специалисты потом придут и смогут правильно ответить на вопрос. А сейчас люди, которые не смогли правильно понять вопрос, начали ставить минусы и закрыли его.

Comment: 6 человек уже выразили свое мнение, что *тема* (в вашей формулировке) недостаточно конкретная. Прислушайтесь )

Comment: В чем проблема формулировки?
"Можно ли как то убрать ограничение чтобы можно было добавлять и миллиарды ключей?"

Comment: С негодованием минусаторами согласен, с непониманием комментариев решительно нет

Comment: Если бы вы знали, сколько хороших вопросов на английском SO заминусовали и закрыли из-за недопонимания! Я вижу такой вопрос, собираюсь ответить, но пока допил чай - его уже закрыли... Поэтому я бы не стал восхвалять одну версию сайта и принижать другую.

Comment: *"Alexey Ten пишет "Живите с этим." В чем ценность подобных комментариев?"* Наверное, ценность - в ссылке на баг в в V8, которая приведена в том же комментарии? А фраза "живите с этим" означает что-то типа "никак, это баг движка". По сути, это ответ на вопрос.

Comment: *"А смысл уводить тему в оффтоп?"* Мне кажется наоборот, вам пытаются помочь решить вашу настоящую проблему (см. ссылку в первом комментарии). Если предложенное альтернативное решение не подходит, объясните комментирующим, почему именно не подходит.

Comment: Ну собственно говоря у меня непонимание почему на вопрос "Как починить карбюратор в жигули 1982г выпуска?" Отвечают: "Купи лучше новый рено логан."

Comment: Ну ответьте "слишком дорошо". :) Я не разбираюсь в теме, но решения, которые предложили в комментариях, не кажутся очевидно нелепыми. Если они чем-то не подходят, скажите об этом комментриющим, может они предложат что-то получше.

Comment: Ваш вопрос чуднее, он скорее - "Как залить в карбюратор жигули 1982г выпуска 600 000 л?"

Comment: @Kromster
Да нет, при 48 млн ключей работает, а при 49 млн уже нет. Интересно разобраться почему. Очевидно есть какой то лимит в конкретном движке javascript и способ его увеличения(или же нет способа). Мне не интересно обсуждать другие методы обхода я это уже сделал давно, мне интересно разобраться в технической особенности. Обычно появляется квалифицированный "товарищ" который подробно расписывает особенности того или много движка и почему так происходит.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Потому что на сайте минусаторы размножились. Вот станет как enSO и можно будет вообще отсюда линять.

Comment: Линька – процесс обновления у животных кожных покровов или их образований: перьев, шерсти, панциря, рогов :)

Comment: Линять куда? Вопросы и ответы мейл ру?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ещё не придумал)))

Comment: "Ответ" звучит так, как будто @Qwertiy уже с enSO слинял. Но ведь нет же.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, у меня там всего [7 ответов](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4928642+is%3Aa+created%3A2021-01-01..2021-11-15) за всю прошедшую часть 2021 года. [В 2020 - 18](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4928642+is%3Aa+created%3A2020-01-01..2020-12-31). [В 2019 - 30](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4928642+is%3Aa+created%3A2019-01-01..2019-12-31). [В 2018 - 19](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4928642+is%3Aa+created%3A2018-01-01..2018-12-31). [В 2017 - 47](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4928642+is%3Aa+created%3A2017-01-01..2017-12-31).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, [В 2016 - 156](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4928642+is%3Aa+created%3A2016-01-01..2016-12-31). [В 2015 - 60 за полгода](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4928642+is%3Aa+created%3A2015-01-01..2015-12-31). Так что вполне можно считать, что я оттуда слинял.

Comment: Нельзя быть немножко беременным. Уменьшение активности - это все же не "вообще линять". Вообще линять - это прекращение активности (хотя бы публично видимой, понятно, что из гугла так или иначе заходить придётся).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, линять можно постепенно)