# Что плохого в моём ответе?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, голоса-против

Автор спросил как сделать без корутин - я даю [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1516224/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-unity-c/1516279?noredirect=1#comment2722343_1516279) как сделать без корутин. Объясняю особенности. aepot мне говорит о какой-то игре, ответ дизлайкают, при этом ответ, который говорит именно про корутины, получает оценки. У меня это вызывает недоумение и вопрос: что в моём ответе плохого, почему его минусят, а ответ, который отвечает противоположное от того, что спросили - плюсуют?

Comment: Ощущение, что пытались направить в нужное русло и исключили заблуждение ТС. А вот по поводу минусов, вряд ли вы получите ответ от тех кто их рассылает)

Comment: Кажется вам в комментариях уже все указали

Comment: @Kromster , тс там написал прямо, что именно это он и хотел получить

Comment: ТС написал *"Вот это мне и нужно, но это работает только в .NET приложениях. В unity это не работает"* - так что с его точки зрения ответ как раз неправильный (хотя у него всего 51 репутации, минус он поставить наверное не мог).

Comment: *"Считаю, что мой ответ чётко отвечает на вопрос тс и его минусят необоснованно"* - к сожалению, наши собственные оценки субъективны. Кому-то может быть кажется, что он умнее всех или быстрее всех, однако только вынеся это на суд других, можно выяснить, так ли это (и то, это будет лишь небольшая выборка субъективных мнений, но чем их больше, тем вероятно четче можно говорить об объективности). Так что если у ответа 3 минуса (и один плюс), то он скорее менее хорош, чем ответ с просто 12 плюсами (например).

Comment: _'aepot мне говорит о какой-то игре'_, речь ведь о движке Unity3d.

Comment: @Nofate но ведь не обязательно делать исключительно игры на этом движке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Между ответом на вопрос автора и ответом который поможет автору есть большая разница. Автор не всегда задаёт правильный вопрос, т.к. не обладает достаточными знаниями. [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy?r=SearchResults)

В вашем случае автору нужно было приостановить метод без корутинов. Ему этого хотелось т.к. он не до конца разобрался в его работе. Но корутины в данном случае это лучшее решение, поэтому хорошим ответом будет тот, который объясняет автору работу корутина.